# How to login and authenticate to Postgresql after a fresh install?

Tags: database, postgresql, authentication, ubuntu, passwords

Did a new install of postgres 8.4 on mint ubuntu. How do I create a user for postgres and login using psql?

When I type psql, it just tells me

```
psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "my-ubuntu-username"
```

Comment: Check this [blog post](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/10/04/ident/).

Answer (score 208, accepted):

There are two methods you can use. Both require creating a user **and** a database.

By default psql connects to the database with the same name as the user. So there is a convention to make that the *"user's database"*. And there is no reason to break that convention if your user only needs one database. We'll be using `mydatabase` as the example database name.

1. **Using createuser and createdb**, we can be explicit about the database name,

   ```
   $ sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER
   $ createdb mydatabase
   $ psql -d mydatabase
   ```

   You should probably be omitting that entirely and letting all the commands default to the user's name instead.

   ```
   $ sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER
   $ createdb
   $ psql
   ```
2. **Using the SQL administration commands, and connecting with a password over TCP**

   ```
   $ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
   ```

   And, then in the psql shell

   ```
   CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypass';
   CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH OWNER = myuser;
   ```

   Then you can login,

   ```
   $ psql -h localhost -d mydatabase -U myuser -p <port>
   ```

   If you don't know the port, you can always get it by running the following, as the `postgres` user,

   ```
   SHOW port;
   ```

   Or,

   ```
   $ grep "port =" /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
   ```

## Sidenote: the `postgres` user

I suggest *NOT* modifying the `postgres` user.

1. It's normally locked from the OS. No one is supposed to "log in" to the operating system as `postgres`. You're supposed to have root to get to authenticate as `postgres`.
2. It's normally not password protected and delegates to the host operating system. This is a **good thing**. This normally means in order to log in as `postgres` which is the PostgreSQL equivalent of SQL Server's `SA`, you have to have write-access to the underlying data files. And, that means that you could normally wreck havoc anyway.
3. By keeping this disabled, you remove the risk of a brute force attack through a named super-user. Concealing and obscuring the name of the superuser has advantages.

Comment: I understand that the problems do not occur if using a DB super user (-s) instead of a non-super user. Next question for me would be, what can be done do get this running even the DB user is not a super user.

Comment: In my case, after creating the user with: $ sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER, I needed to configure a Password with:  ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'mypass'; ( after logged in postgres with: sudo -u postgres psql )

Comment: How should I understand the command `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`? I understand `sudo` means root privilege, `-u postgres` means log in as user `postgres`, `psql` is the command to connect to `postgresql`, but what's the last `postgres` doing ?

Comment: Is this really making it the user's database?  logging in as the user, I did `show config_file` and `show data_directory` and apparently the `data_directory` still belongs to user `postgres`..

Comment: I'm kind of lost why under linux `postgres` would put data directory under `/root` by default; database is of arbitrary usage, all sorts of data could go into a database and that's almost surely user action, not root action.

Comment: this is great but one thing that is missing is the password. Is it not best practice to include a password for the newly created user? or has this been omitted by design? please clarify.

Answer (score 60):

by default you would need to use the postgres user:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Comment: Or if you can't use sudo, do this: "su postgres" and then "psql"

Comment: What is the benefit to switching to postgres? `sudo -u postgres`? Would it be better just to `psql -U postgres`?

Answer (score 45):

The error your are getting is because your-ubuntu-username is not a valid Postgres user.

You need to tell psql what database username to use

```
psql -U postgres
```

You may also need to specify the database to connect to

```
psql -U postgres -d <dbname>
```

Comment: I tried "psql -U postgres", got the same error.

I haven't created any database yet, just made a fresh install.

Comment: `psql -U myuser -d mydb` works perfectly, while `psql -U myuser` tries to use peer auth, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

The main difference between logging in with a postgres user or any other user created by us, is that when using the postgres user it is NOT necessary to specify the host with **-h** and instead for another user if.

### Login with postgres user

```
$ psql -U postgres
```

### Creation and login with another user

```
# CREATE ROLE usertest LOGIN PASSWORD 'pwtest';
# CREATE DATABASE dbtest WITH OWNER = usertest;
# SHOW port;
# \q

$ psql -h localhost -d dbtest -U usertest -p 5432
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172588/5279996)

Answer (score 5):

you can also connect to database as "normal" user (not postgres):

```
postgres=# \connect opensim Opensim_Tester localhost;

Password for user Opensim_Tester:    

You are now connected to database "opensim" as user "Opensim_Tester" on host "localhost" at port "5432"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your database client connects with TCP/IP and you have ident auth configured in your pg_hba.conf check that you have an identd installed and running. This is mandatory even if you have only local clients connecting to "localhost".

Also beware that nowadays the identd may have to be [IPv6 enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112/is-there-a-identd-like-package-in-ubuntu-that-supports-ipv6) for Postgresql to welcome clients which connect to localhost.

Answer (score 2):

For example, first, you can log in to PostgreSQL to use `postgres` database of the user `postgres` just after the installation as shown below:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password for user postgres:
```

Then, you can create the user(role) `john` with the password `banana` as shown below. *By default, PostgreSQL needs a password so you should set `PASSWORD` and you can omit `WITH` which is optional and you must use `''` for `PASSWORD` instead of `""` otherwise there is error:

```
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'banana';
```

Then, you can create `apple` database with the owner `john` as shown below. *If you omit `OWNER`, the current user(role) `postgres` is the database owner:

```
CREATE DATABASE apple OWNER john
```

Then, exit PostgreSQL:

```
\q
```

Then, you can log in to PostgreSQL to use `apple` database of the user(role) `john` as shown below. *If you don't specify database, the specified user is looked for as database so `john` database which doesn't exist is looked for:

```
psql -U john apple
```

Or:

```
psql -U john -d apple
```

Or:

```
psql --username=john --dbname=apple
```

Or:

```
psql --username john --dbname apple
```

Then, you need to input the password `banana` after running the command above:

```
Password for user john:
```

In addition, you can log in to PostgreSQL to use `apple` database of the user(role) `john` without password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana psql -U john apple
```