# PostgreSQL under Lion: What's the password?

Tags: macos, postgresql, passwords, osx-lion

I got my new lion machine. Ran the PostgreSQL installer from the PostgreSQL site for Mac and i have no multiple apps installed. One of them is "pgAdmin III.app". When I open it there is already one server connection available. localhost:5432

Whenever I try to connect to the server with a doubleclick the programm asks me for a password. I have no idea what to enter. It's not my admin password, it's not "postgres", it's not "localhost", it's not empty.

I just can't seem to connect to the server. Even when I check the properties of the localhost server the password field seems empty. However I'm not allowed to leave the password field empty.

Any idea what to do? I really need to setup postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tried it on OSX, but on Ubuntu you can login as the system user 'postgres' to the default database 'postgres' without a password with

```
su postgres -c psql
```

You can then (re)set the password of the database superuser 'postgres'.

You can also edit the configuration file `pg_hba.conf` (don't know where it is located on a default OSX installation, on Ubuntu it is `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf`) and grant access to the default database without authentication

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    postgres    postgres    127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

After editing pg_hba.conf you must reload the configuration with

```
pg_ctlcluster 8.4 main reload
```

You can then connect with pgAdmin and (re)set the password, but don't forget to change the authentication method back to `md5` again...

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the pg_hba.conf file. it's not in `/private/var/` since there is not even a `pgsql` directory. When I try to run `su postgres -c psql` and enter my computer passphrase the  console says "Sorry"

Comment: I found quite a lot of links regarding this issue, however no one has this password problem. Most of the described problems are a failed installation. http://od-eon.com/blogs/calvin/os-x-lion-postgresql/ 

E.g. I found this - http://xiphone.org/how-to-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/ - it says `/usr/local/pgsql/` I do not even have this pgsql directory in `/usr/local`Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with PostgreSQL on OSX at all, so I don't know where the PostgreSQL folders and files *should* be located after a successful installation. But `su postgres -c psql` as root should definitely work with a default configuration.

Comment: @tscho, the `psql` command doesn't run on OSX (HighSierra) so these instructions cannot be followed

Answer (score 9):

On my Mac OSX Lion, PostgreSQL configuration files are stored under `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/data/`

Answer (score 2):

here's a better answer (works in OSX HighSierra): the account used is the one you're logged onto OSX with, therefore, the password is your password!

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked a short time ago. The steps described there should be appropriate for Lion also.

[Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/7696398#7696398)

Comment: Thank you but I can't seem to find `pg_hba.conf` I have no idea where this file is located on a mac. I just found a lot of _conf.sample files inside /usr/share but no `pg_hba.conf` file. Any idea where this file could be?

Comment: You could try the command `locate pg_hba.conf`. A quick google brought up `/private/var/pgsql/pg_hba.conf`. Since I'm not on Lion, _I_ cann't look :-)

Comment: @A.H. you sir are a life saver!  I didn't have a `pg_hba.conf` all I had was a sample file of it

Comment: `locate pg_hba.conf` (on OSX HighSierra) comes up empty.  suggestions?