# How can I start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

#### Final update:

I had forgotten to run the `initdb` command.

---

By running this command

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
```

I see that `postgres` is not running

```
> ps auxwww | grep postgres
remcat          1789   0.0  0.0  2434892    480 s000  R+   11:28PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

This raises the question:

How do I start the PostgreSQL server?

Update:

```
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting
sh: /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log: No such file or directory
```

Update 2:

The *touch* was not successful, so I did this instead:

```
> mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres
> vi /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
> ls /usr/local/var/postgres/
server.log
```

But when I try to start the Ruby on Rails server, I still see this:

> Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Update 3:

```
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
pg_ctl: no server running
```

Update 4:

I found that there ***wasn't any*** *pg_hba.conf* file (only file *pg_hba.conf.sample*), so I modified the sample and renamed it (to remover the .sample). Here are the contents:

```
 # IPv4 local connections:
 host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust
 # IPv6 local connections:
 host    all             all             ::1/128                trust
```

But I don't understand this:

```
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
pg_ctl: no server running
```

Also:

```
sudo find / -name postgresql.conf
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

Update 5:

```
sudo pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
Password:
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process.
```

Update 6:

This seems odd:

```
> egrep 'listen|port' /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
egrep: /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf: No such file or directory
```

Though, I did do this:

```
>sudo find / -name "*postgresql.conf*"
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
/usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

So I did this:

```
egrep 'listen|port' /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'        # what IP address(es) to listen on;
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
                # supported by the operating system:
                #   %r = remote host and port
```

So I tried this:

```
> cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf
> cp /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf
```

I am still getting the same "Is the server running?" message.

Comment: How did you install Postgres?  Did you use a package manager or a manual installation?

Comment: can't remember exactly but it was either installed already or i ran "brew install postgres". I'd lean towards the latter but again, i'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Use `sudo`, ie `sudo pg_ctl...`

Comment: I have the same error, any updates on this?

Comment: @SAnandNarayan, in the end, i found that i needed to run the initdb command. How did you install postgres?

Comment: @Ramy yes initdb solved the issue

Comment: I had this same issue. If your postgres server is running (check using ps aux | grep postgres) and psql still says server not running: creating a postgresql.conf file by copying the postgresql.conf.sample worked

Comment: I up-voted this just because the FINAL UPDATE made me laugh very hard! :D

Comment: Had to upvote, I come here at least 3 times a week to copy the very first pg_ctl command to restart psql after an unexpected termination.. heh I gotta learn it :D  Thanks dude!

Comment: I simply followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700596/homebrew-postgres-broken) and it did the trick

Comment: After stumbling on this issue every few months, I wrote a gist for myself in 2017 that I refer back to every time homebrew upgrades my psql version and leaves my postgres setup borked. Happy to share if it helps someone else! https://gist.github.com/hartleybrody/b0975ef3450995db58b247e1f5859a2d

Comment: If you are like me and think that you need to "start the database" when in fact all you want is to start working with the database then launch "pgAdmin".  That's the equivalent of SQL Server Management studio for us Microsoft backgrounded folks.

Answer (score 2096, accepted):

The [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager includes launchctl plists to start automatically. For more information, run `brew info postgres`.

#### Start manually

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

#### Stop manually

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop`

#### Start automatically

"To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:"

`brew services start postgresql`

---

What is the result of `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`?

What is the result of `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status`?

Are there any error messages in the server.log?

Make sure tcp localhost connections are enabled in pg_hba.conf:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

Check the listen_addresses and port in postgresql.conf:

`egrep 'listen|port' /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf`

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'        # What IP address(es) to listen on;
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
```

---

**Cleaning up**

PostgreSQL was most likely installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or the [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx) installer.

Check the output of the following commands to determine which package manager it was installed with:

```
brew && brew list|grep postgres
fink && fink list|grep postgres
port && port installed|grep postgres
```

Comment: i tried to 'touch /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log'. no luck though

Comment: @Ramy Did the touch succeed?  Check the existence and permissions of */usr/local/var/postgres* and *server.log*.  It should be rw for your userid.

Comment: @Ramy: Can you include any information in /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log?  Your installation may be corrupt and it may be faster to clean up and re-install using a known source such as Homebrew.

Comment: @Ramy: I updated my answer to include a method to determine how Postgres was installed.

Comment: ok, this is getting ridiculous. i ran "brew list | grep postgres" and got a one line response: "postgres". So, i assumed this meant that I installed postgres with Homebrew. I then uninstalled postgres with "brew uninstall postgres" and then removed the postgres tarball from the cache in case it was corrupted during download ("rm /Users/remcat/Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.0.4.tar.bz2"  ). I  then started the server with the the pg_ctl command you show in your answer. I made sure that the pg_hba.conf was updated properly. still getting the same "is the server running" message.

Comment: I just had to `mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres` and it started right up.

Comment: If this is your first install, create a database with: `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` ... Success. You can now start the database server using: `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: Why is all this necessary? Why can't you just start postgres the way you start node?

Comment: If you're trying to use an existing brew installed version after an upgarde you can switch to it as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula I just needed `brew switch postgresql 9.2.1` as `which pg_ctl` was coming up blank.

Comment: one nitpick `brew && brew list|grep postgres` doesn't actually display postgres from my brew list. However `brew list|grep postgres` does.

Comment: @JamesA Can you explain the syntax of the startup line `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start` ? How exactly does this command work?

Comment: what a ridiculously complicated command just to start and stop the program

Comment: I literally have to look this up at least twice a week haha

Comment: pg_ctl: server does not shut down

Comment: This still works but is a little out of date. The answer below `brew services start postgresql` is a more up to date, and straightforward answer.

Comment: I discovered that using 'pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start' threw permissions errors that enabled me to sort out why 'brew services start postgresql' stated the service was started even through postgresql service was not started.

Comment: Is it possible that they changed the folder name from `postgres` to `postgresql` recently?

Answer (score 510):

If you want to manually start and stop PostgreSQL (installed via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))), the easiest way is:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

and

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

If you have a specific version, make sure to suffix the version. For example:

```
brew services start postgresql@10
```

Comment: I wish I knew about `brew services` sooner... this is the only solution that's working for me. <3 thanks!

Comment: `brew tap gapple/services` will make the brew services command work again

Comment: Looks like `brew tap homebrew/services` still working https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Comment: This works **after** `initdb` has been successfully run. Otherwise it silently fails (but appears to have worked, with the service showing as *started* in `brew services list`.

Comment: I needed to run `brew services restart postgresql`, since starting the db with pg_ctl or `brew services start` said "another server might be running" and and stoping the db with pg_ctl hung.

Comment: Important note - this will cause postgres to always start when your computer starts. If you want to start postgres as you please, use `pg_ctl`

Comment: I also had to `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832331/4754881).

Answer (score 190):

I had almost the exact same issue, and you cited the initdb command as being the fix.  This was also the solution for me, but I didn't see that anyone posted it here, so for those who are looking for it:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

Comment: this worked for me also, initdb told me that I had already the config done, so I deleted the entire directory: "rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres" ran again your command and my server now gets up and running, many thanks sir!

Comment: yep I had to run `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres` and then this worked for me

Comment: This is what worked for me as well. Before initdb, I had to also chown the postgres dir (`chown _your username on your comp_ usr/local/var/postgres`), then initdb. After that the server starts automatically when you restart (if you followed Homebrew's instructions for that) or manually `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`.

Comment: After `initdb` (including removing the old directory if necessary), `brew services start postgresql` works

Comment: If the idea of `rm -rf`ing everything that's currently in your database scares you a bit, instead of deleting it entirely, you could use something like `mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres.backup` to move it to a new backup directory, then run the command to get the database started again.

Answer (score 128):

### If your computer was abruptly restarted

---

You may want to start PG server but it was not.

First, you have to delete the file `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` Then you can restart the service using one of the many other mentioned methods depending on your install.

You can verify this by looking at the logs of Postgres to see what might be going on: `tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

For specific version:-

```
 tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres@[VERSION_NUM]/server.log

Eg:

 tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres@11/server.log
```

Comment: You can check `tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` to see if you should delete that file. ref https://coderwall.com/p/zf-fww/postgres-on-osx-with-homebrew-not-running-after-osx-crash

Comment: Mine was under /Users/<user>/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.6/postmaster.pid

Comment: for homebrew installs the path is `~/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Comment: Wow... only this worked for me! Can you please give a more detailed explanation why we should delete `postmaster.pid` if the computer was abruptly restarted?

Comment: This was really useful

Comment: my postmaster.pid was at "/usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6" as I have installed 9.6 version using brew. Removing  postmaster.pid helped me as postgres did not start properly.  then need to run "brew services restart postgresql@9.6"

Comment: I cant start my pg using other answer, but after try to delete `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`  like your answer, it's WORKED!!!...

Comment: Removing `postmaster .pid` helps. Thank you!

Comment: It was the solution for my problem, thx!

Answer (score 80):

Another approach is using the *lunchy* [gem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) (a wrapper for launchctl):

```
brew install postgresql
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
gem install lunchy
```

To start PostgreSQL:

```
lunchy start postgres
```

To stop PostgreSQL:

```
lunchy stop postgres
```

For further information, refer to: *"[How to Install PostgreSQL on a Mac With Homebrew and Lunchy](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/)"*

Comment: depending on how you setup postgres you may need to use postgresql instead of postgres

Answer (score 78):

Here my two cents: I made an alias for *postgres pg_ctl* and put it in file *.bash_profile* (my PostgreSQL version is 9.2.4, and the database path is */Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data*).

```
alias postgres.server="sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data"
```

Launch a new terminal.

And then? You can start/stop your PostgreSQL server with this:

```
postgres.server start
postgres.server stop
```

Comment: Specifying the data directory with -D is the key here

Comment: I kept getting "Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process." when running just sudo. +1

Comment: Thanks. The postgres tools' suggestions to use su fail miserably. sudo -u works brilliantly. (on El Capitan)

Answer (score 33):

The cleanest way *by far* to start/stop/restart PostgreSQL if you have installed it through `brew` is to simply unload and/or load the [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) configuration file that comes with the installation:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

The first line will stop PostgreSQL and the second line will start it. There isn't any need to specify any data directories, etc. since everything is in that file.

Comment: works great for PostgreSQL 9.5.3 installed on OS X via Brew!! thanks!

Comment: this works like a charm when postgres server is not shutdown properly and is not accepting incoming connections

Comment: Homebrew itself has simple wrappers for these commands, e.g: `brew services start postgres` (and stop). Throw a `-v` on the end and you can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 29):

To start the PostgreSQL server:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

To end the PostgreSQL server:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

You can also create an alias via CLI to make it easier:

```
alias pg-start='pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start'
alias pg-stop='pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast'
```

With these you can just type "pg-start" to start PostgreSQL and "pg-stop" to shut it down.

Comment: I got error `pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" is not a database cluster directory` how to fix this?

Answer (score 27):

For test purposes, I think PostgreSQL App is the best option!

Run an app, and the server is up and running.

Close the app, and the server goes down.

http://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 14):

```sh
# Remove old database files (if there was any)
$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres

# Install the binary
$ brew install postgresql

# init it
$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres

# Start the PostgreSQL server
$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

# Create your database
$ createdb mydb

# Access the database
$ psql mydb
psql (9.0.1)
Type "help" for help.
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have installed using Homebrew, the below command should be enough.

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

This sometimes might not work. In that case, the below two commands should definitely work:

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes it's just the version which you are missing, and you are scratching your head unnecessarily.

If you are using a specific version of PostgreSQL, for example, PostgreSQL 10, then simply do

```
brew services start postgresql@10

brew services stop postgresql@10
```

The normal `brew services start postgresql` won't work without a version if you have installed it for a specific version from [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)).

Answer (score 10):

When you install PostgreSQL using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)),

```
brew install postgres
```

at the end of the output, you will see this methods to start the server:

```
To have launchd start postgresql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load postgresql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I think this is the best way.

You can add an alias into your *.profile* file for convenience.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and performed all updates from the first post. But after checking the log file,

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

I see the true cause:

```
FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has group or world access
DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
```

After changing permissions on this directory,

```
chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/postgres
```

the PostgreSQL server started.

Check the log file every time.

Answer (score 7):

Variation on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103603/2394728

```
initdb `brew --prefix`/var/postgres/data -E utf8`` &&  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data -l logfile start
```

Comment: You should add a link to the answer you refer to.

Comment: This was helpful as my pg was working fine and all of sudden it stopped working and could not find /var/postgres folder.

Comment: Could someone please comment as to why this is superior to the linked answer? As I saw I already upvoted from the last time I had a similar problem I'm going to use it since there's no reason given here.

Answer (score 7):

For a quick disposable test database, you can run the server in the foreground.

Initialize a new PostgreSQL database in a new directory:

```
mkdir db
initdb db -E utf8
createdb public
```

Start the server in the foreground (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop the server):

```
postgres -d db
```

In another shell session, connect to the server

```
psql -d public
```

Comment: This seems great but doesn't work for me - it wasn't the server to already be running in order to do the createdb step. When I try to start the serve it says it needs the PGDATA or config-file, which don't exist yet. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

If you didn't install it with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) and directly from the Mac package, this worked for me for PostgreSQL 12 when using all the default locations, variables, etc.

```
$ sudo su postgres
bash-3.2$ /Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/12/data/ stop
```

Comment: This worked for me as I had installed postgreSQL using .dmg file.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

- install postgresql using brew: `brew install postgresql`, you can specify the version using "@" sign: `brew install postgresql@14`
- start postgresql: `brew services start postgresql` or specific version `brew services start postgresql@14`
- stop postgresql: `brew services stop postgresql`

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL is integrated in **Server.app** available through the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_%28iOS%29) in [Mac OS X v10.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion). That means that it is already configured, and you only need to launch it, and then create users and databases.

**Tip**: Do not start with defining $PGDATA and so on. Take file locations as is.

You would have this file:
*/Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Config/org.postgresql.postgres.plist*

To start:

```
sudo serveradmin start postgres
```

**Process started with arguments:**

/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/postgres_real -D /Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Data -c listen_addresses=127.0.0.1,::1 -c log_connections=on -c log_directory=/Library/Logs/PostgreSQL -c log_filename=PostgreSQL.log -c log_line_prefix=%t  -c log_lock_waits=on -c log_statement=ddl -c logging_collector=on -c unix_socket_directory=/private/var/pgsql_socket -c unix_socket_group=_postgres -c unix_socket_permissions=0770

**You can sudo:**

```
sudo -u _postgres psql template1
```

**Or connect:**

```
psql -h localhost -U _postgres postgres
```

You can find the data directory, version, running status and so forth with

```
sudo serveradmin fullstatus postgres
```

Comment: Couldn't find much else that showed how to use the built in Postgres. Helped me find serveradmin command as well. Thanks

Comment: Running a service as root user (sudo) is definitely not a good idea, as soon as there is a security issue, the whole computer is compromised.

Comment: The postgresql is not running as root, but as _postgres.

Answer (score 5):

For development purposes, one of the simplest ways is to install Postgres.app from the [official site](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/). It can be started/stopped from *Applications* folder or using the following commands in terminal:

```
# Start
open -a Postgres

# Stop
killall Postgres
killall postgres
```

Comment: `killall` is probably not the best way to stop a database.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me ([macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra)):

```
sudo -u postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_ctl start -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
```

Or first

```
cd /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/
```

Answer (score 4):

[Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) is the way!!

To start the service:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

To list it:

```
brew services list | grep postgres
```

To stop the service:

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed PostgreSQL using the EnterpriseDB installer, then what [Kenial suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x/16128223#16128223) is the way to go:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/{version}/data start
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/{version}/data stop
```

Answer (score 2):

For [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), just use the load/unload command and the port name of the running server:

```
sudo port load postgresql96-server
- or -
sudo port unload postgresql96-server
```

so you don't have to remember where the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql96.plist` file is located.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't install the Postgres server with Homebrew or installed using .dmg file, try this:

```
$ sudo su postgres
bash-3.2$ /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/ stop
```

Answer (score 2):

having installed Postgres with `homebrew` that is what I do to start postgres and keep it in foreground to see the logs:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ brew upgrade postgres`

fixed it for me.

That, of course, will upgrade your PostgreSQL version and update/install any dependencies.

***Warning***: Do this knowing that your PostgreSQL version will likely change. For me, that wasn't a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers fixed the issue for me, despite getting the same error messages.

I was able to get my instance back up and running by deleting the existing *postmaster.pid* file which was locked and was not allowing connections.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me every time, inspired by Craig Ringer:

```
brew install proctools
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

*proctools* includes *pkill*. If you don't have Homebrew: https://brew.sh/

Answer (score 1):

After doing brew services restart postgresql.

It works best to:
brew services stop postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
brew services start postgresql

Then type: psql

**it now runs this** was after the error:
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

The **upgrade** may be **optional** depending on the other dependencies your running.

Which means that rather than Restart using brew for in on mac os, Stop completely postgres and then start postgres and connect to your psql databaseName.

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X, I really like [LaunchRocket](https://github.com/jimbojsb/launchrocket) for this and other background services I used in development.

This site has nice [instructions on installation](http://macappstore.org/launchrocket/).

This gives you a nice screen in your System Preferences that allows you to launch, reboot, root, and launch at login.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake: Check whether you're inside a [Tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) or [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) instance. Starting won't work from there.

From: *[Error while trying to start PostgreSQL installed via Homebrew: “Operation not permitted”](https://superuser.com/questions/879640/error-while-trying-to-start-postgresql-installed-via-homebrew-operation-not-pe)*

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is some edge case that maybe will be helpful for someone:

There is an option that you will have postgres.pid filled with some PID.
If you restart your machine, and before PostgreSQL will be back again, some other process will take that PID.

If that will happen, both the *pg_ctl* status and *brew* service are asked about the PostgreSQL status, will tell you that it is *up*.

Just do `ps aux | grep <yourPID>` and check if it is really PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I tried all of these solutions, but none worked.

I finally managed to get it working by changing the PostgreSQL `HOST` in [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) settings from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary components to PostgreSQL: the database server and a client.

There is an included client via the CLI, or like me, you might be used to tools like [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin), so it requires a separate GUI client.

For example, on macOS: install `Postgres.app` which is ~65 MB from: https://postgresapp.com/

Then follow [these instructions](https://postgresapp.com/):

- install and initialise the server with the button on the right.
- update your `$PATH` using terminal: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp`
- and finally, install the `pgAdmin` GUI which is about ~100 MB from: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/

Answer (score 0):

Here the user that is executing the command is not a Postgres user. Because of that most people face **Permission denied** problem

```
> ./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/data start 
  pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

You have to switch to Postgres user and then need to execute the command

```
sudo -u postgres ./pg_ctl start -D /Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/data/ 
sudo -u postgres ./pg_ctl stop -D /Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/data/
sudo -u postgres ./pg_ctl reload -D /Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/data/
```

Answer (score -1):

### Here is an easy and always forking solution (mac os):

**(WARNING: IT WILL DELETE ALL YOUR DATABASES)**

1. Stop the postgres service:

   brew services stop postgres
2. Delete all files in "postgres" directory:

   rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres/*
3. Initialize the new database system:

   initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
4. Start postgres:

   pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l server.log start