# Unable to start sever, likely due to misplaced .conf. How do can I verify the cause and find/replace .conf?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I'm new to psql, and am having some issues that I think are being caused by a misplaced .conf file.  When I tried to log into a database I created earlier I get an error

```
$ psql corporation
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
```

Based on the [psql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html) it looks like the server isn't running and ps confirms this.  Since I don't remember having to start it last time I used psql I was a little confused, but it seemed easy to fix.  Unfortunately, my attempts to start the sever have not worked. Using the first method suggested by the docs gets me

```
$ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

While the second method results in

```
$postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
[1] 3165
```

Ps confirms that neither of these methods started postgres, and when I tried to open the database anyway, to double check, it returns a slightly different error message than before.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[1]+  Exit 2                  postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data > logfile 2>&
```

[How to start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x) seems related, but has some gaps.  Just running initdb wasn't enough, and I don't seem to have a .conf.sample.  Do I just need to create a new .conf from scratch or what?
For reference I'm running Snow Leopard, I originally tried to manually instal psql, but ended up installing brew then brew installing psql.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to run initdb after installing the binaries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `find`?

```
sudo find / -name postgresql*
```

Comment: I just tried that and got just tried that and got
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
/Applications/Anki.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql
And so on for more denied permissions than will fit into this comment box.  However it looks like it did find a .conf.sample file which for some reason didn't show up when I searched with spotlight. I will see I can apply how to start postgresql server on mac os x's steps from here.  Thanks, I'd upvote you, but apparently I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put sudo at the front. Updated.

Comment: Ok, I was able to find a .conf file and change the path I was using so  it works now. I don't know why find worked when finder didn't, but the problem is solved.

Comment: Sweet. Mark my answer to get a higher rep.  And it's okay, the finder only shows files in the userland by default, if I recall. Drives me batty.