# sudo: unknown user: postgres

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm currently trying to run postgresql (9.3) on my iMac but I have some issues with user postgres and psql connection.

I bought an iMac old generation (with snow Leopard) that was migrated to Lion. As followed on other StackOverflow topics I added this line on my .bash_profile :

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

When launching pg :

```
sudo su postgres -c '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/ -m fast start'
```

it returns :

```
su: unknown login: postgres
```

What should I do ?

Comment: You need to create a user account called postgres on the system, or connect to postgresql using a different account that already exists (assuming it has permission for the operation).

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3 is a **beta version** which at this time, should be used only to test and report bugs to the PostgreSQL developers. Use 9.2 instead.

Answer (score 34):

The default postgres user in OSX 10.8 & 10.9 should be `_postgres`, you can use `sudo -u _postgres` to run the command

Comment: This is what I was missing

Answer (score 22):

I got this same error (`su: unknown login: postgres`) when trying `sudo su - postgres`. I then managed to log in using `sudo psql -U my.username postgres`.

I could then create the appropriate users, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start from current user:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/ -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Additional info: [How to start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I tried this command line but there is no /bin directory in PostgreSQL/9.3. Should I add it ? I did probably a mistake on my bash_profile. I heard also the path /usr/var changed into usr/local/var on Lion. Could it come from this ?

Comment: @user1713964 No, it seems your postgresql installation broken. Why not remove old installation and install using homebrew (http://brew.sh) package manager? brew install postgresql --without-ossp-uuid

Comment: Just did it and I have same issue :/

Comment: I installed with homebrew and there is no `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.x/data/`