# PostgreSQL could not create any TCP/IP sockets' Mavericks

Tags: postgresql, macos, sockets, tcp

I'm installing through brew.

The error message(s):

When I call

```
postgres
```

I receive the error

```
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and  retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

Running

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Creates the same error

```
createdb
```

prompts me for my password twice, then says,

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "thomasmurphy"
```

What I've tried
* Uninstalling and reinstalling the pg gem, uninstalling and reinstalling postgres
* Updating command line tools
* Satisying all of brew doctor's needs
* editing pg_hba.conf's permissions
* editing .bash_profile to be sure it includes the above directories

I have Postgres running perfectly on my work computer, also on Mavericks, so this strikes me as somewhat of an edge case. What other vectors can I poke at to try to solve this?

Comment: `Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?` - well, is it?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Fair question. But no, no connections are running on 5432.

Comment: I entered localhost:5432 into my browser and received 'no data received', which, you know, does in fact sound as if a server is running but isn't sending a response. Is that accurate to your understanding? Is there a bash shell command I should be issue that is less clumsy than that?

Comment: Haven't had a mac for a few years. Do you have lsof (http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) or netcat (http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) installed? Try `lsof -i -n -P | grep 5432` or `nc localhost 5432`. Failing that `ps auxw | grep postgres`.

Comment: Sounds good. I also have an Ubuntu VM on that box, so I'll give it a shot on there too to narrow down possibilities of what's going wrong.I'm starting to suspect that the issue is that it's not authenticating me as a super user to access the root account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The errors you are getting are because PostgreSQL is running.  How do I know?  Because it is rejecting your password.  That's pretty clear.

Now your real problem is probably that you need to restart PostgreSQL after modifying the pg_hba.conf to give you trust access.  Then you can:

```
 ALTER USER foo WITH PASSWORD 'bar';
```

In terms of starting and restarting PostgreSQL, please see this question:  [How to start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue anymore, since I clean installed PostgreSQL on this machine. This answer seems to align with the issue I was having, so I'll accept.

Answer (score 18):

The error you got is because your host is broken. Check your `/etc/hosts` file.

Put `127.0.0.1 localhost` at the first line of hosts.

Comment: It worked in my case, but I can not explain why? Can you also tell what was wrong in not having that entry in hosts file.

Comment: The  localhost is not same as 127.0.0.1. In some applications, the localhost don't need to be translate to IP address. However, it

Comment: However it need to be translate here.Both of the PostgreSQL and hosts configure file don't set up an association between the localhost and IP.

Answer (score 4):

Linux: Make sure that your loopback interface is up by running the  `ifconfig`  at the command line. If it's not up, you can use  `/sbin/ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1`  to bring it up.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: My man! Thanks a million. I never would have thought of this.

Answer (score 3):

A machine reboot resolved the error for me.

Comment: Strange but this worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple scenarios and places to check in this case. Got lost once because of this.
A usual default `hosts` file should look like one below:

```
[root@localmachine ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

To confirm `localhost` is able to resolve, test using `ping`:

```
[root@localmachine ~]# ping localhost
```

Check `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf|grep hosts` and confirm `files` is there:

```
#     hosts: files dns
#     hosts: files dns  # from user file
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:     files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

Check permissions of `/etc/hosts` file, it should be `644` ( readable for all processes/users` ):

```
[root@localmachine ~]# ls -al /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 240 Aug 14 08:04 /etc/hosts
```

For those who have enough time, I've created a detailed blog post here: 
https://coffeewithbytes.com/blog/postgres-hostsfile-permissions/

I've mentioned how I checked and came to a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be that your `/etc/hosts` is broken.  It could be something else breaking DNS lookup of `localhost`, *even if the correct line is in `/etc/hosts`*.

Check `nslookup localhost` and see if you get `127.0.0.1` as a result.  Also check with `getent hosts localhost`.  Check these also *as the user Postgres runs as.*

Comment: The `hosts` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is possibly relevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed another version of Postgres previously? In my case, I was trying to execute:

`sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

that was **incorrect!!** finally I found the correct one is:

`sudo systemctl restart postgresql-12`

I had two versions of Postgres...

Answer (score -1):

#### Could not create TCP/IP connection or could not connect to localhost

A TCP/IP reset helps solve the problem after a full day of several different techniques. It turned out that the problem was with my PC due to bad TCP/IP configuration.

I used the following commands to achieve the reset.

1. Reset the Windows Socket Catalog (winsock). You could read more on [winsock](https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-winsock/)

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

2. Reset the TCP/IP:

```
netsh int ip reset
```

You will then restart your PC/system so that the configuration reset can work.

If you couldn't understand this, watch the video explanation on [Landon Johnson's channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaWIPsvWZx8)

Comment: This was usefull for me and solves my problem

Answer (score -2):

I know its quite an old issue but I wanted to post what worked for me first I ended every postgres task on task manager.
Secondly I purged and reinstalled postgressql again using these method below

First remove the installed postgres:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgr* 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then install 'synaptic':

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install Postgres

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Wallah it works. Warning it may affect your other projects who may be running on port 5432.Beware.

Comment: The question is asking about a Mac problem.