# Problems with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am just getting started with ruby on rails and heroku. I am following the getting started guid on herokus website but have ran into a problem. I have logged into heroku, created an app as such `rails new myapp --database=postgresql` and then created a controller `rails generate controller welcome index` in the `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` I just created a header saying hello world. When I start a local server and go to it, I get `could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` and the output listed bellow in the terminal I followed another tutorial just for setting up rails without heroku and created the app like this `rails new blog` and then did the same as created a controller like in the heroku tutorial and everything worked fine, so I assume the problem is with `rails new myapp --database=postgresql` How would I fix this?

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:548:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4242016335734095215__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/mattmoss/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (18.2ms)
```

Here is my database.yml

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  password:

development:
  host: localhost

test:
  host: localhost
```

Comment: start here.. and make sure you have Postgres running locally, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x

Comment: "no such file or directory" usually indicates a socket problem.

Comment: How would I fix this (I started learning yesterday) @PeterWooster

Comment: see my answer, but I'm no expert on Postgres, look for questions about unable to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 2):

In your `config/database.yml`, try adding

```
host: localhost
```

in each of your development and testing environment or more specifically looking at your existing `config/database.yml` shown above:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Hope this helps

Comment: after adding this, it says `database configuration does not specify adapter` when I go to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: can you add your original `config/database.yml` file to your question?

Comment: You don't need to add a separate `development:` just add `host: localhost` underneath your existing `development:` in the beginning of your `config/database.yml` file you already have, I have edited my answer showing this

Comment: ok so now I am getting `could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what your issue is, I would double check how your installed postgres on your mac, one way of install postgres on your mac is using http://www.postgresapp.com/, sorry I couldn't be more of assistance

Answer (score 2):

On most *nix servers "localhost" is handled through a Unix style socket.  If you use 127.0.0.1 instead it will use TCP/IP.  Try that or make sure your client and server are using the same socket address and that it is actually a usable *nix socket.

There is a configuration parameter in database.yml that lets you set the socket address, be certain that you have access to the directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

I hear Heroku has made some changes to the db connection behaviour. For rails version >= 4.1 it does not overwrite your config/database.yml - it merges with it. First you need to visit https://postgres.heroku.com/databases and click on your database. You should look that parameter in the pic below

[image: img1]

Use that variable for your production parameter like so

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL'] %>
```

This is what worked for me after trying different things. I hope this helps someone.