# hello postgres database connection errors Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i'm new to ruby on rails, i'm trying to run an app with postgres database, but it didn't  work, i have tried to search lots of information, but i wasn't  useful, Someone posted the exactly same question here [Problems with rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690245/problems-with-rails-server) , I tried to use command `rails new blog` it created an app with sqlite3 database, it works fine, but i created app with command `rails new myapp --database=postgresql` after that i visit localhost page, it ocurred  the exactly same  error

could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Can anyone help? it would be very much appreciated.

database.yml file information:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Can you include your config/database.yml file in your question please?

Comment: Hello, i have just included the yml file, Thank you very much

Comment: please include pg_hba.conf

Comment: Did you check your db is actually running on it's default port? Also what environment you're currently running the app in?

Comment: Hello, i'm  a beginner,I couldn't  find pg_hba.conf.  I am running it on my local MAC OS 10.9.4 ,Thank you guys.

Comment: @Snailwalker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025972/postgresql-how-to-find-pg-hba-conf-file-using-mac-os-x

Comment: I followed that link , it returned only:" Snailwalkers-MacBook-Pro:~ snailwalker$ ps aux | grep postgres
snailwalker       452   0.0  0.0  2432784    488 s000  R+    3:20PM   0:00.00 grep postgres "                                            But no format  ... -D .... E.G: as they mentioned.

Comment: Have you actually installed postgres?

Comment: i checked with brew list command, i think i have installed 
apple-gcc42 automake gcc46  gmp4  libiconv libmpc08 libxml2  libyaml  openssl  pkg-config ppl011
autoconf cloog-ppl015 git  libgpg-error libksba  libtool  libxslt  mpfr2  ossp-uuid postgresql readline

Comment: Hello guys, After i reinstall home brew, use brew doctor command, and follow the instruction and reinstall postgres after that. i solved the problem. haha i think i messed up the evrionment . This is the link  http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this file:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

Original Answer: [psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks for Answering this question, i think your comment inspired  my to solve the issue, It's related. Here is the link i followed up with, i reinstalled home-brew and Postges http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/