# psql: could not connect to server

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

The error in its entirety reads:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the
>   server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

This is my second time setting up Postgresql via Homebrew on my Mac, and I have no clue what is going on. Previously, it had been working. At some point, I must've entered a command that messed things up. I'm not sure. Now, whenever I enter a SQL command from the command line, I receive the above message. I've run a command to check whether the server is running, and it apparently is not. If I attempt to start the server using

> $ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

I receive the following error:

> postgres cannot access the server configuration file
>   "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Postgresql via Homebrew, but the problem persists. I'm completely at a loss as to how to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

your data directory is most likely wrong.

issue a "sudo find / -name "postgresql.conf" " on your terminal to see where your postgres file resides. Then, do an `ls` in the data directory. Use that in the `-D` option when starting postgres.