# django.db.utils.OperationalError Could not connect to server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am not sure how to fix this issue

I have no idea why I am getting this error when I try to `runserver`:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1085589b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 184, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.get_table_list(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 165, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 138, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 134, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I try to connect to postgres:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'beerad',
        'USER': 'bli1',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the contents of your settings.py (especially the part on databases)?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It can be some issues:

1. PostgreSQL is not running. Check it with sudo `service postgresql status`
2. Your PostgresSQl is not running on port 5432. You can check it typing `sudo netstat -nl | grep postgres`
3. You have something wrong trying to connect to your db like the username, the password or the databasename. Check that they are what postgres ask for you to connect it and that is the db_name that you want to access to.
4. Problems with postmaster.pid in postgres. It can happen because of a shutdown unproperly done. It makes to remind a pid alive that doesn't allow your server start. To fix it you have to:

   ```
    * rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid 
    * pg_resetxlog -f /usr/local/var/postgres
   ```

   After this it should run properly if you make the runserver of postgres

Help in Mac OSX: [How to start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I tred the 2 commands you provided: `bash: service: command not found
` and `netstat: lunt: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`

Comment: now it is updated, it should work. Netstat is native of unix systems

Comment: `netstat: lnt: unknown or uninstrumented protocol` =/

Comment: ok try with sudo nestat -nl, I think it doesn't like the -p v.V

Comment: I got a huge output. Is there something specific I should look for?

Comment: You forgot to update and add the `| grep postgres` but I added it and I did not get anything as output

Comment: yes, if postgres is running on the 5432 port. You can grep it like sudo netstat -nl | grep postgres

Comment: and what did the 1. instruction gave to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76515/discussion-between-ricardo-burillo-and-liondancer).

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm running my app hosted on heroku. Though everything works fine when running the app using the Django development server as well as the heroku local web, but gives me the error when i hit the url for hosted app. I get the same error when I try to "heroku run python manage.py migrate".

Comment: Thank you. I ran this line `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` and then `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` and the server started and everthing now works fine

Comment: `ss -ltpn |grep 5432` or `ss -ltp |grep postgres`

Answer (score 7):

Try killing all postgres processes. Im on a MAC and this solution that I've found on ubuntus forum really works.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/547434/how-to-nicely-stop-all-postgres-processes
[image]

Answer (score 7):

**For Windows**

Go to search bar and just write "`Open psql`" and hit Enter.

Once screen is opened, rerun django project.

Comment: It did work, but how comes

Answer (score 5):

In my case, all was set up well and Postgres had the right port, PostgreSQL was running normally, but the 5432 port was being shared with phppgadmin, I could access the phppgadmin that gives me web access to Postgres database server, but my Django application was not working it would return Connection refused error. so I changed the port number on the phppgadmin config file (/etc/phppgadmin/config.inc.php) to 5433 from 5432 and all worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

In MacOS I stopped and restarted postgresql according to the advice given in this StackExchange answer:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171580/182403

```
brew services stop postgresql
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid # adjust path accordingly to your install
brew services start postgresql
```

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the server solved the problem on my side.

Answer (score 3):

### In **project_folder/settings.py** under `DATABASE` - `HOST` settings you should use local IP (127.0.0.1) not your public IP.

#### Correct

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'yourdb',
        'USER': 'youruser',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourpass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

#### Incorrect

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'yourdb',
        'USER': 'youruser',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourpass',
        'HOST': '188.252.196.234 ',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This error occurs when an improper system shutdown has been done. I'm on an M1, and I've installed PostgreSQL via Homebrew.

I tried to start PostgreSQL after receiving an error identical to yours using `brew services start postgresql`, but I got this error:

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/adithraghav/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.
```

So, I tried to stop the running instance and start it again with `brew services restart postgresql`.

This line gave me the following output:

```
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
```

I checked the port on which PostgreSQL was running with `sudo netstat -nl | grep postgres`, but received no output.

So I deleted the existing `postmaster.pid` file with this:

```
rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

NOTE: If you are not on an M1 Mac, you have to run `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`.

Then, I ran `pg_resetwal -f /opt/homebrew/var/postgres` to reset the write-ahead log. (NOTE: From Postgres 10 and onwards, `pg_resetxlog` has been renamed to `pg_resetwal`).

Now, `python3 manage.py runserver` works with no issues :)

Answer (score 2):

The following command works for me (Windows)-

```
pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data" restart
```

Then run server again-

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are seeing this error while using PostgresSQL from Google Cloud follow all configurations as mentioned in
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment#macos-64-bit

Also separate the HOST configuration as below

DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '/cloudsql/'
if os.getenv('GAE_INSTANCE'):
pass
else:
DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'

This helps in resolving this error.

Answer (score 1):

Go to aws instance -> security groups -> source -> inbound -> ::0

Answer (score 1):

You might not connecting to the right database. If you are using Docker be sure you are using 5432 as port at the outside of the image.

eg:

db:
image: postgres:12.0-alpine
volumes:
- postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
env_file:
- ./postgres/.env
ports:
- **5432**:5432

Answer (score 1):

One problem that I found common with Django/Postgres (especially with Docker) is that your Django Web App maybe starting up before your Postgres server starts up. If the other solutions don't work, try to restart your Django App after start up. With Docker, the command would be `docker restart <web-app container name>`

Comment: you simple add depends_on on the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable listen addresses if you are using remote database.

```
cd /etc/postgresql/12.x/main/
```

open file named postgresql.conf

```
sudo nano postgresql.conf
```

add this line to that file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

then an open a file named pg_hba.conf

```
sudo nano pg_hba.conf
```

and add this line to that file

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

restart your server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the port is in use. I fixed this stopping my postgre service in windows from services.msc

Answer (score 0):

I was using a tunnel to connect to my database through a docker container. The connection worked fine when using pgAdmin but the docker container I was using had its own network and so connections to the tunnel were denied by default. I had to modify my connection string to allow connections from other hosts, ie. `0.0.0.0`.

```
ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:5432:db_name.private_db_host:5432 target_user@public.tunnel.target.ip
```

Make sure you are on a private connection if you're doing this.