# Postgresql: migrating local database to the PythonAnywhere database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pythonanywhere

I've followed the Djangogirls tutorial and usually the tutorial calls for you to create a database on `pythonanywhere`.  This usually works without a hitch when using `sqlite3` however this time I'm using `postgresql` and I got the below error when I ran the `migrate` command in the console:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or          directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql
```

What does this mean exactly?

using `python 3.5.1`
`django 1.9.8`
`postgresql 9.4`

Thanks

Ok after reading around some more, this is my problem in a nutshell.

I have postgresql running locally.  I then deployed the wbapp onto pythonanywhere.  Whilst there I tried to create the database by running migrate which resulted in the above error.

Since then i realised that I had to setup postgresql to run on pythonanywhere.  I followed the instructions and did that, but what I don't understand is do I now have to create the database from scratch? And if that is the case what happens to all my tables etc. from my local database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django.db.utils.OperationalError Could not connect to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937378/django-db-utils-operationalerror-could-not-connect-to-server)

Comment: Are you actually running postgres on that server?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  How would I check that?

Comment: Well, if you haven't done anything to run it, then you aren't. How are you expecting this to work?

Comment: The server is definitely running locally.  The problem has occured when I try to deploy on pythonanywhere

Comment: Ok after reading around this is my problem in a nutshell.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify, you should not be trying to connect to your local postgres. Instead, you should setup postgres on pythonanywhere, and make sure that your django settings.py is pointing the database address and port to the pythonanywhere database. Which is not local to the console/webapp server that you are running your code on. Instead, go to the pythonanywhere database tab and look at the address/port that is given to you.

Answer (score 3):

According to their [help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Postgres/) you need to upgrade to a paid account to be able to use postgres.