# django..db.utils.operationserror on port 5432

Tags: python, django

I am getting that error, along with message TCP/IP connections on port 5432.
I HAVE installed psycopg2 2.8.4m, running Django 3.0 and python 3.6
I get that error, when I run my application firs ttimne.I am still unable to run my app first time.

Is it because database not created yet? and I tried solutions posted here [django.db.utils.OperationalError Could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937378/django-db-utils-operationalerror-could-not-connect-to-server) but it did not help

Comment: Can you show your `DATABASES` setting? You could also try with `psycopg2-binary`

Comment: Hi, I had to do sudo-apt install postgres for it to work.