# Unable to figure out what's missing to run my Django Project successfully

Tags: python, django, postgresql, visual-studio-code, pgadmin-4

Last year, I created a Django project on real estate business. Few days back, I cleaned up my PC & I believe I removed something useful because of which I'm unable to run it on my localhost now. It was working fine before.

The major tools that I used in the project include Django, PostgreSql, pgAdmin4, Bulma. As I'm trying to run it via VSCode, it's showing the following traceback. Please help me find out what's exactly missing and how can I get back the proper working flow.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection       
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

[Here's](https://github.com/Kalpana98/estate_deal) the GitHub link to the source code of my entire project.

Comment: Your postgresql is either not running or not configured to accept TCP connections. Search Stack Overflow for previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Kalpana Upadhyay

It is the issue with `PostgreSQL`. There are a lot of possibility for this issue

From `Ricardo Burillo` suggestion

1. `cmd` : `sudo service postgresql status` if PostgreSQL is not running.
2. `cmd` : `sudo netstat -nl | grep postgres` Your PostgresSQl is not running on port 5432. You can check it by execute this `cmd`.
3. Problems with postmaster.pid in Postgres. It can happen because of a shutdown unproperly done. It makes to remind a PID alive that doesn't allow your server to start. To fix it you have to

   - `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`
   - `pg_resetxlog -f /usr/local/var/postgres`

For more suggestion, you could check this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937378/django-db-utils-operationalerror-could-not-connect-to-server) if may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the latest version of PostgreSql & pgAdmin which somehow worked. Although I had to set up the entire database thing once again as follows -:[image]