# Django ASGI/Daphne: postgres connection timeout

Tags: python, django, postgresql, asgi

In my project I am using a PG database. Now that I've deployed the app to the production server, I' ve switched from the test db (PG 10) to the production db (PG 9). When connecting the Django backend to the test db, everything works perfectly fine, but when I connect it to the production db, it works only for a couple minutes and then, after some time of inactivity for example, the whole site stops working properly.

This is the data from daphne:

[log on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWcQs.png)

What pg settings could cause this? I don't really think that it's an issue with the app's config, because with the other db everything is working correctly. This prod_db is placed on an external server btw.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937378/django-db-utils-operationalerror-could-not-connect-to-server) might help you

Comment: Well, I can connect to the db, it doesn't refuse connection. It simply stops responding after some time I think...