# The command I run to restart PostgreSQL deletes all my data. How should I restart to keep my data?

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My biggest problem is that every time i turn off my laptop i lose all my data. I just started learning rails with postgres.

So how can i start and stop properly a postgres database on the terminal.

I'm on Mac OS X.

this is what i use to start it:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data
```

and this to stop it:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8 but i think what it does it removes it so i lose all my data
```

Comment: Using the `pg_ctl` comand? `pg_ctl stop`.

Comment: postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data
this is what i use to start it 
and this to stop it
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
but i think what it does it removes it so i lose all my data

Comment: Yes, `rm` deletes data.

Comment: Never run a command without knowing what it does.

Comment: how is your Postgres server _started_? If that is registered as a service in the system, a clean shut down of the operating system should also cleanly shut down Postgres - at least this happens on Windows and Linux. As the MacOS is a "Unix-Style" OS at heart it should work there as well (I have never used a Mac). How did you install Postgres? How do you turn off your Mac?

Comment: Augh. Yes, you are saying "Delete all my data, then create a new blank PostgreSQL install". That is why you have a new blank PostgreSQL install when you run it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer** (If you don't have time):

```
pg_ctl stop -m immediate
```

That should do an instant shutdown, with an implied auto-recovery (no data loss). But this is not always recommended, read below for why.

**Long Answer**: 2 Things need to be taken note of:
  1. You should lookup [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-ctl.html#APP-PG-CTL-OPTIONS). The -m option allows three modes. Depending on whether this is a heavy production box or your local system you need to chose between the three options (fast / smart / immediate). The implications of all three are given if you search for the word 'Immediate' on this page.
  2. Read the [Description](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-ctl.html#APP-PG-CTL-DESCRIPTION) section nonetheless, regarding the Modes to gain more clarity about why there is no one solution for all problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting your PostgreSQL install then creating a new one.

Your commands:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres &&
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8 &&
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data
```

do:

- Delete PostgreSQL data directory, removing all data
- Create a new blank PostgreSQL instance
- Start the PostgreSQL instance

Clearly this is not what you want.

You should instead use the documented method of starting and stopping your particular PostgreSQL install. Since you're using `/usr/local/var/postgres` I'm guessing you're using Homebrew to install PostgreSQL, so see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975660/398670). Basically, install a launchd plist file and use launchd.

Don't run commands you don't understand, and read the documentation; you'll have fewer of this kind of problem.