# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03A69780>

Tags: python, django

I am currently undergoing a python course and learning how to use Django. I have just created mysite and am currently trying to test the Django server.

I ran the command below in the cmd and the output is as follows.

> C:\Users\Win10\Desktop\Python\Newsite\mysite>python manage.py runserver

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03A69780> 

Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
        module = import_module(entry)   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
    _call_with_frames_removed   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from django.contrib.admin.filters import (   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\filters.py", line 10, in <module>
        from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 12, in <module>
        from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets   

File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py", line 151
        '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
        ^ 

SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Hope that i can be advised on this thank you! :(

Comment: @VineethSai have not coded anything actually.. what do you mean by possible duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to update your Django version. Look [Here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28814).

Try removing the existing version of django,

```
pip uninstall Django
```

and then reinstall using

```
pip install Django==1.11.17
```

Hopefully, that should fix the problem.

Comment: I found a solution online and it says to pip install django==1.11.17 and it worked for me! However, I would like to know if there may be any complications in future. Thank you!

Comment: No there won't be any complications. Although it would be better to use 2.x versions because django would be stopping support for 1.x versions after python 2.x hits end of it's life. That would be around 2020. Here's the Roadmap https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/

Comment: Ah alright. Thank you so much! Just saw your update on the above. Have a great day.