# using huggingface Trainer with distributed data parallel

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

To speed up performace I looked into pytorches [DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html) and tried to apply it to transformer [Trainer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html).

The [pytorch examples for DDP](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html#comparison-between-dataparallel-and-distributeddataparallel) states that this should **at least** be faster:

> DataParallel is single-process, multi-thread, and only works on a single machine, while DistributedDataParallel is multi-process and works for both single- and multi- machine training. DataParallel is usually slower than DistributedDataParallel even on a single machine due to GIL contention across threads, per-iteration replicated model, and additional overhead introduced by scattering inputs and gathering outputs.

My DataParallel trainer looks like this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import torch
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, BertConfig

training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=os.path.join(path_storage, 'results', "mlm"),  # output directory
        num_train_epochs=1,  # total # of training epochs
        gradient_accumulation_steps=2,  # for accumulation over multiple steps
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,  # batch size per device during training
        per_device_eval_batch_size=4,  # batch size for evaluation
        logging_dir=os.path.join(path_storage, 'logs', "mlm"),  # directory for storing logs
        evaluate_during_training=False,
        max_steps=20,
    )

mlm_train_dataset = ProteinBertMaskedLMDataset(
        path_vocab, os.path.join(path_storage, "data", "uniparc", "uniparc_train_sorted.h5"),
)

mlm_config = BertConfig(
        vocab_size=mlm_train_dataset.tokenizer.vocab_size,
        max_position_embeddings=mlm_train_dataset.input_size
)
mlm_model = ProteinBertForMaskedLM(mlm_config)
trainer = Trainer(
   model=mlm_model,  # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
   args=training_args,  # training arguments, defined above
   train_dataset=mlm_train_dataset,  # training dataset
   data_collator=mlm_train_dataset.collate_fn,
)
print("build trainer with on device:", training_args.device, "with n gpus:", training_args.n_gpu)
start = datetime.now()
trainer.train()
print(f"finished in {datetime.now() - start} seconds")
```

The output:

```
build trainer with on device: cuda:0 with n gpus: 4
finished in 0:02:47.537038 seconds
```

My DistributedDataParallel trainer is build like this:

```
def create_transformer_trainer(rank, world_size, train_dataset, model):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'
    os.environ["RANK"] = str(rank)
    os.environ["WORLD_SIZE"] = str(world_size)

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=os.path.join(path_storage, 'results', "mlm"),  # output directory
        num_train_epochs=1,  # total # of training epochs
        gradient_accumulation_steps=2,  # for accumulation over multiple steps
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,  # batch size per device during training
        per_device_eval_batch_size=4,  # batch size for evaluation
        logging_dir=os.path.join(path_storage, 'logs', "mlm"),  # directory for storing logs
        local_rank=rank,
        max_steps=20,
    )

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,  # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
        args=training_args,  # training arguments, defined above
        train_dataset=train_dataset,  # training dataset
        data_collator=train_dataset.collate_fn,
    )
    print("build trainer with on device:", training_args.device, "with n gpus:", training_args.n_gpu)
    start = datetime.now()
    trainer.train()
    print(f"finished in {datetime.now() - start} seconds")


mlm_train_dataset = ProteinBertMaskedLMDataset(
    path_vocab, os.path.join(path_storage, "data", "uniparc", "uniparc_train_sorted.h5"))

mlm_config = BertConfig(
    vocab_size=mlm_train_dataset.tokenizer.vocab_size,
    max_position_embeddings=mlm_train_dataset.input_size
)
mlm_model = ProteinBertForMaskedLM(mlm_config)
torch.multiprocessing.spawn(create_transformer_trainer,
     args=(4, mlm_train_dataset, mlm_model),
     nprocs=4,
     join=True)
```

The output:

```
The current process just got forked. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, please explicitly set TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
The current process just got forked. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, please explicitly set TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
The current process just got forked. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, please explicitly set TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
The current process just got forked. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, please explicitly set TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
The current process just got forked. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, please explicitly set TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
build trainer with on device: cuda:1 with n gpus: 1
build trainer with on device: cuda:2 with n gpus: 1
build trainer with on device: cuda:3 with n gpus: 1
build trainer with on device: cuda:0 with n gpus: 1
finished in 0:04:15.937331 seconds
finished in 0:04:16.899411 seconds
finished in 0:04:16.938141 seconds
finished in 0:04:17.391887 seconds
```

About the inital forking warning: What is exaclty forked and is this expected?

And about the resulting time: Is the trainer incorrectly used since it seemed to be a lot slower than the DataParallel approach?

Comment: Regarding the warning: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691279/how-to-disable-tokenizers-parallelism-true-false-warning/62703850#62703850).

Comment: Regarding your actual question. The trainer API does actually [support](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#transformers.TFTrainingArguments) distributed training. Some of the slower performance can probably be explained by distributing something which also tries to distribute.

Comment: I saw that it supports distributed training, but did not find any examples. So I was wondering if the implementation I posted uses the API correctly

Comment: Well I haven't worked with it yet, but when the documentation says it supports distributed training, why should you be required to use `torch.multiprocessing`? Also as you can see from the output the original trainer used one process with 4 gpus. Your implementation used 4 processes with one gpu each. That means the original implementation has already scattered the data.

Comment: the idea of DistributedDataParallel is to have multiple processes with one gpu each. So yes my output is exactly what I would want it to look like. And me using `torch.multiprocessing` is exactly why I was asking if it is correct or if there is a built-in way to do this.

Comment: I am not sure about the whole implementation but at least the fast tokenizers use multiple processes by itself.

Comment: Do you find the correct implementation or is this the correct one?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the correct implementation, but it does work in principle. Also the API has had a lot of updates since this post so I am not sure if it still works.

Comment: your title of the questions needs drastic improvements. Say what issue you have there directly and unambiguously.

Comment: do you have an example of a full notebook of how to run ddp with hf's trainer? in particular I want to know if: wrap the model in DDP?
change the args to trainer or trainer args in anyway?
wrap the optimizer in any distributed trainer (like cherry? cherry is a pytorch lib for things like this)
also, what about the init group that is usually needed?
Do you know/mind to share code?

Answer (score 4):

Kind of late to the party but anyway. I'm going to leave this comment here to help anyone wondering if it is possible to keep the parallelism in the tokenizer.

According to this [comment on github](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/issues/660#issuecomment-740453885) the **FastTokenizers** seem to be the issue.
Also according to [another comment on gitmemory](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/huggingface/transformers/10400/786133504) **you shouldn't use the tokenizer before forking the process.** (which basically means before iterating through your dataloader)

So the solution is to not use FastTokenizers before training/fine-tuning **or** use the normal Tokenizers.

Check the huggingface documentation to find out if you really need the FastTokenizer.