# Setting Hugging Face dataloader_num_workers for multi-GPU training

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pytorch-dataloader

Should the HuggingFace transformers [TrainingArguments](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.19.4/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments) `dataloader_num_workers` argument be set per GPU? Or total across GPUs? And does this answer change depending whether the training is running in [DataParallel or DistributedDataParallel mode](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/perf_train_gpu_many#data-parallelism)?

For example if I have a machine with 4 GPUs and 48 CPUs (running only this training task), would there be any expected value in setting dataloader_num_workers greater than `12` (48 / 4)? Or would they all start contending over the same resources?

As I understand when running in DDP mode (with `torch.distributed.launch` or similar), one training process manages each device, but in the default DP mode one lead process manages everything. So maybe the answer to this is `12` for DDP but `~47` for DP?

Comment: curious, did this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017931/using-huggingface-trainer-with-distributed-data-parallel

Comment: do you have an example of a full notebook of how to run ddp with hf's trainer? in particular I want to know if: wrap the model in DDP?
change the args to trainer or trainer args in anyway?
wrap the optimizer in any distributed trainer (like cherry? cherry is a pytorch lib for things like this)
also, what about the init group that is usually needed?
Do you know/mind to share code?