# Trying to connect Express server to make POST/GET requests to PostgreSQL database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, react-redux

I have looked around for a solution, but I can't seem to figure this out. What I'm trying to do is make POST/GET requests to a PostgreSQL database from an Express server.

**main.js:**

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on localhost:${port}`);
});
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

**app.js:**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var helmet = require('helmet');

var indexRouter = require('./routes'); 

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js (Handling the api requests)**

```
router.post('/api/post/userprofiletodb', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req);
    const values = [req.body.profile.nickname, req.body.profile.email, req.body.profile.email_verified];
    // ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING - prevents the user profile from being stored in db twice
    await pool.query(`INSERT INTO users(username, email, email_verified, date_created)
                VALUES($1, $2, $3, NOW() )
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, values,
                (q_err, q_res) => {
                    if (q_err) return next(q_err);
                    console.log(q_res);
                    res.json(q_res.rows);
                })
})

router.get('/api/get/userprofilefromdb', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req);
    const email = String(req.query.email);
    await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1`, [email],
    (q_err, q_res) => {
        if (q_err) return next(q_err);
        res.json(q_res.rows);
    })
})
```

**db.js:**

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'mydb',
    password: 'mypassword',
    post: 5432
});

module.exports = pool;
```

**React code (Action Creators for Redux):**

```
export const setDbProfile = (profile) => async(dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/post/userprofiletodb', profile);
    dispatch({ type: SET_DB_PROFILE, payload: response.data });
    console.log(response);
    history.replace('/');
}

export const getDbProfile = (profile) => async(dispatch) => {
    const data = profile;
    console.log('getDbProfile', profile);
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/get/userprofilefromdb',
        {
            params: {
                email: data.profile.email
            }        
        }
    )
    dispatch({ type: GET_DB_PROFILE, payload: response.data });
    history.replace('/');
```

Here is my thought process:
- I have my Express server set up on http://localhost:8000 and my React application is running on http://localhost:3000 (I have already included a proxy in the package.json file).
- When the action creator is called, it first does a post request to http://localhost:8000 where my Express server is on.
- The Express server sees this and makes a request to the PostgreSQL database stored on localhost: 5432.

However, I'm getting this error....

```
POST /api/post/userprofiletodb 500 182.558 ms - 250
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
GET /api/get/userprofilefromdb?email=dasfdfasfdf@gmail.com 500 52.541 ms - 250
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
```

I think there may be an issue with my PostgreSQL database. How I set that up is by opening up SQL Shell (psql) and did the following:
- CREATE DATABASE mydb;
- \c mydb
- CREATE TABLE users(...);
- CREATE TABLE posts(...);
- CREATE TABLE comments(...);

Not too sure how I could solve this... Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

**UPDATE:**
When I run the command

```
netstat -na
```

I do not see, 127.0.0.1.5432 listed at all... Does this mean my database is just not setup properly?

**Running SQL Shell (psql)**

```
x-MacBook-Air:~ x$ /Library/PostgreSQL/12/scripts/runpsql.sh; exit
Server [localhost]: 
Database [postgres]: 
Port [5000]: 5432
Username [postgres]: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Press <return> to continue...
```

Comment: Can you access the database via `psql` command line interface?

Comment: `x-MacBook-Air:~ x$ /Library/PostgreSQL/12/scripts/runpsql.sh; exit
Server [localhost]: 
Database [postgres]: 
Port [5000]: 5432
Username [postgres]: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Press <return> to continue...`

Ya, I realized that's what I had to try and I get this error

Comment: @Danizavtz I edited the post to make it easier to look at :) I tried using a different port setting up the psql terminal... but I guess that's not the same?? I'm not too sure

Comment: Maybe you can try some alternatives contained here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x