# Unable to connect to server postgresql error

Tags: postgresql, macos, ssh, port, homebrew

I am not able to connect to postgresql server. The connection was working fine till yesterday, but since today morning I am having this issue. I installed postgres using homebrew, and have already uninstalled and reinstalled it. Below is the screenshot from pgAdmin 4:

[image]

I am not able to find postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf  as multiple solutions suggested to change listen_addresses. I see that postgresql is installed, this is the location: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14. I have tried solutions from:
[How can I start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x)
but almost for all commands I am getting the error:
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

If I try to change the location in command([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x#:~:text=I%20start%20the-,PostgreSQL,-server%3F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x#:%7E:text=I%20start%20the-,PostgreSQL,-server%3F)) to start the server, I get the error: pg_ctl: directory "/opt/homebrew/postgres_db_cluster" does not exist.

The worst part is that it was working all good till yesterday.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1: As suggested in comments , I followed the steps from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew, but still getting the error.
Step 1: brew services restart postgresql@14
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
==> Successfully started `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
Step 2: psql postgrespsql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Edit 2:
I tried the first step from this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x?rq=1#:~:text=on%20port%205432%3F-,Update,-3%3A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x?rq=1#:%7E:text=on%20port%205432%3F-,Update,-3%3A)
below is the result:

```
abhinash.kumar@ ~ % pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" is not a database cluster directory.
```

also, the link mentions a file pg_hba.conf.sample, but I cannot find that in my system.

Edit 3: Starting postgres server using homebrew

```
abhinash.kumar@ ~ % brew services start postgresql@14     
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/abhinash.kumar/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist` exited with 5.
```

continues to throw errors.

Comment: Since you installed with Homebrew use the commands shown here [Homebrew](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew).

Comment: Try to stop the postgres on your computer, or changing the password, it seems it have a problem trying to access the port 5432

Comment: I have uninstalled and then installed postgresql. and it throws the same error. creating a new connection through pgAdmin is not working as well.

Comment: Best guess is the server is running on a different port. In terminal do: `sudo lsof -P -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN | grep postgres` and see what port is listed.

Comment: the command lists no result.

Comment: Then try: `sudo lsof -U | grep postgres`.

Comment: This command as well gives no result.

Comment: `ps ax| grep postgres`  or `ps ax| grep post` return anything? If not then the server did not start contrary to the message.

Comment: this is the result: 13621 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep postgres

Comment: 1) Quit trying random examples from the Internet that is creating more confusion then enlightenment. 2)  This `13621 s000 S+ 0:00.00 grep postgres` means the server is not running.

Comment: well, this question is related to starting server- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-can-i-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x. I tried, and added as an Edit to the question. doesn't look like working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247801/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-abhinash-jha).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver, the problem is now fixed.
I uninstalled postgres, and reinstalled using homebrew. In addition, I ran this command:
initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres/.
and this fixed the issue, and I am able to create the db connection using pgAdmin 4.