# pgAdmin:Password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I Installed PGadmin9+ in my ubuntu machine few month back but i lost the password of default database `postgres` . Now when i am trying to connect with `postgres` DB i am getting error

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How to change the password? or recover it?

I did not installed `PostgreSQL`   from command prompt so [This SOlution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)  is not working any alternative solution.

Comment: What did you try and what failed exactly?

Comment: I Just run the Pgadmin3 try to login the db but password not worked so i tried  the link given in question.