# Postgres 11 default password (homebrew)

Tags: postgresql

Various guides show how to install/start postgres on mac using brew:

```
brew install postgresql
brew services start postgresql
```

However the usual next step, to connect with an empty password, fails.

```
psql postgres
Password for user <>:
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

How do you connect to a newly created postgres 11 database on mac in 2019?

---

Prior research:

It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769579/default-password-for-my-user-in-postgresql) the default password used to be empty.

The [official wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew) guide, and [Recent](https://www.robinwieruch.de/postgres-sql-macos-setup/)/[fairly recent](https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb#3-configuring-postgres) tutorials   suggest `psql<databasename>` should just work, but these fail with the above errors.

An [older guide](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-the-default-password-for-postgresql/) and [newer SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161836/1609929) have you switch user before using psql, which gives the same error as above.

Comment: Note the official wiki seems to have a typo: i'm replacing `pgsql` with `psql`. The recent guide inclused creating a database as a step, and instead fails with `createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user`.  The service is always started after installing:  ```brew services start postgresql```  ```Service `postgresql` already started, use `brew services restart postgresql` to restart.```

Comment: still not answered... yikes. I don't know if it will help now but you could try adding tags such as your operating system or brew to bring it to a wider pool of potential answerers

Answer (score 1):

1. login on your machine in a shell as „root“
2. change to the „postgres“ user:

`$ su - postgres` (no password required because you are `root`)

3. run psql

`$ psql`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a brew installed Postgres@14. The following got me into the DB shell:

```
psql -h localhost -d postgres
```