# What is the default password for Postgres

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have just install Postgres 9.3 on Windows 7. The installation completed successfully. It has never asked me to provide the password for postgres user.

The service postgresql-x64-9.3 is up and running. However, I cannot connect: I do not not know the password. I've found the following answer, but it did not help:

[similar question on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/576623/default-password-for-postgresql Although it says that it asked for the password.

Comment: What program are you using to connect to DB?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mine didnt.

Comment: I just experienced a scenario in PG12 where it did not ask me for password or port.

Comment: Unfortunantly, It didn't

Comment: Same happened for me in pgAdmin4, username : postgres and password : postgres worked out.. Leaving here in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: "I find it hard to believe that a thing which happens to everyone but me, happens." -- Top comment

Comment: I'm using Postgres 13 and my problem was that I was referencing a user that did not own the database, so the password was wrong. Be sure to check if you've made this mistake too!

Comment: In my case it was: username: postgres, password: appmanager. 
I was working with ManageEngine:
https://pitstop.manageengine.com/portal/en/kb/articles/how-to-reset-applications-manager-login-password-for-admin-account

Answer (score 93, accepted):

---

**WARNING**: `trust` means exactly that. Anyone who can connect to the PostgreSQL server can control it. If you set `trust` mode that allows superusers like user `postgres` (or `all` users) to connect, they get total control of your PostgreSQL and can probably run shell commands too. You should usually only use it to *change the password* then restore the configuration back to the auth mode you were using before.

---

If you used an unattended installer script, the password will be in the script or associated config file.

Otherwise, treat it the same as if you lost/forgot the password rather than never knowing it:

- Edit `pg_hba.conf`, setting the auth mode to `trust` instead of the default `md5`
- In the Services control panel restart the PostgreSQL service
- Connect with `psql` or PgAdmin or whatever
- `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'mynewpassword';`
- Edit `pg_hba.conf` again and set the auth mode back to `md5`
- Restart PostgreSQL again

`pg_hba.conf` is in your data directory. By default it'll be `%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.3\data`.

To edit it you'll have to use the security tab to give yourself read/write permissions (via a UAC prompt). This might require you to set yourself as the owner of the file.

---

On unix systems it's more secure to prepend a

```
local all all peer
```

line to `pg_hba.conf` and then `sudo -u postgres psql` (assuming your PostgreSQL server runs as user `postgres`) to get an interactive `psql` session without using a password. That way you don't have to use `trust`.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on newer versions of PostgreSQL. I'm running PostgreSQL 11 on MacOS, the auth mode in `pg_hba.conf` is `trust`, but still I get the authentication error.

Comment: @ataravati Yes, it does. Possibilities: You have edited the wrong `pg_hba.conf` (you have more than one postgres data dir). You forgot to reload the PostgreSQL configuration or restart the PostgreSQL server after editing the config file. There are lines before the entry/entries you edited/added that match so your `trust` entries never get matched. You are connecting over unix socket (`local`) or TCP/IP (`host`) mode, and only edited the config for the other auth mode, try the other connection mode and check both are edited.

Comment: This was the only sensible answer that worked for me - thank you.

Comment: This should be the top voted answer. Still works today in 2023.

Answer (score 150):

**[WINDOWS]**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108276/1087499

**[LINUX]**

might work for windows too

After installing postgres follow following steps in order to setup password for default system account of Linux execute following in terminal:

```
user:~$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@user:~$ psql
```

after executing above two commands you will get into postgres shell

Execute this query in postgres shell:

```
postgres=# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'mynewpassword';
```

your new password is `'mynewpassword'` without quotes and now you can connect with external GUI tools like DBeaver

Comment: Really bad answer. What is the password for postgres to allow me to do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, psql asks for a password when running it. The issue is i don't know that password, so telling me to bypass this step so i can change the password when i can't get in to run that command isn't helpful for me.

Comment: This answer works great. Just make sure you haven't changed anything since the installation.

Comment: @Owl If your system asks for a password when you run $sudo -i -u postgres, it is most likely asking for *your* password since you used sudo.

Comment: I can run this just fine, but on attempting to authenticate, no, that password that I set is not accepted. "Peer authentication failed for user "postgres". Right after I supposedly altered the user postgres and set the password.

Comment: If there are issues still after following this, try this for an alternative - 
sudo su postgres
psql -p 5460 (different port)

Comment: Not working with a fresh Postgres 14 on Ubuntu 22.04 for me.

Comment: Whilst a perfectly fine answer (for linux), I'm astonished as to why this is the top answer. The question is about windows, this answer is for Linux. There's a perfectly fine "windows" accepted answer that still works in 2023 to modify the password. Upvote that one everybody!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and I don't know why over 100 people decided to blindly vote yes on it.

Comment: the question has a "windows" tag so this doesn't answer the question. refer to craig's answer for the actual solution for windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108276/1087499

Answer (score 31):

By default user `postgres` does not have a password

Start psql and create a password:

1. `sudo -u postgres psql`
2. `\password postgres` - It will ask you enter a password for user `postgres`

Comment: It's best to cite a reference to back up your answer.

Comment: I am not sure why the below command:
```
postgres=# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'mynewpassword';
```
returned:
```
ALTER: command not found
```
But your mentioned way worked fine for me. Now I can connect to DBeaver.

Answer (score 21):

On initialisation you can access the DB as:

Username: postgres

Password: postgres

Comment: No, it's not though :(

Comment: Works on PostgreSQL 14

Answer (score 6):

Through trial and error I found that the password for Postgre SQL 10 for the username postgres is "admin". I kept typing in different password until I reached that password. I am using pgAdmin 4 to test out my SQL Statements, POSTGRE SQL 10 is the first server connection set up using localhost.

Comment: No, it's not admin for me either.

Answer (score 3):

## Real Windows Solution

None of the answers here worked for me, in particular all of the popular answers are exclusively for Linux environments, despite the original question asking for Windows instructions. Here's what I found:

When you install PostgreSQL using the regular installer, it asks for a password in the installation process. If you run `psql.exe` and enter that password, it won't work.

The problem is that PostgreSQL chooses the logged in Windows user as active user, but that is not the default user that was created; which is called `postgres`. Under Linux, you can run commands as another user using `sudo -u <user>`, but that's just not a thing on Windows. Instead, you have to use the command line option from `psql` to specify the user to be `postgres`:

```bash
psql.exe -U postgres
```

Then enter *the password you specified during installation* (not "postgres" again!).

Afterwards you can change your password, add users etc. as explained elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there was no default password, but `psql` wouldn't accept a lack of a password (`fe_sendauth: no password supplied`). To get around this, I opened pgAdmin, then in the left sidebar:

- `Servers`
- `Login/Group Roles`
- Right click `postgres` and click `Properties`,
- Go to `Definition` tab
- Set the password in the `Password` field

After saving, `psql` accepted that password. There may have been a switch I could have supplied to have it accept a lack of a password (`--no-password`?), but the user should probably have a password anyways, so this seemed reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I've found is just to install PgAdmin and connect to the local server with the current Windows credentials (username + password). Then you can change the password to the postgres user.

Answer (score 0):

go to control >> computer management >> Locaol users and group >> users >> 
right click on openpgsvc >> set password.
after that now you can access with this password on openpgsvc

Answer (score 0):

I installed PostgreSQL via winget and didn't encounter a password field. For me the default password was `postgres`. I looked into the installer script from winget and there wasn't any password set.

I thought my password was different but in fact I just had to restart my PC after installing it.

Answer (score -5):

step1: Go to control panel 
Step2: Click on Administrative Tools 
Step3: Click on Computer Management
Step4: There under "Local Users and Groups" Double click on user

Step:5: then right click on postgres and you can set password
refer this below image

Comment: there is no posgres user unless manually created outside installer in windows.

Comment: you can set any password