# Password authentication fails with complex password

Tags: python, postgresql, passwords, psycopg2

I wrote a Python script which connects to the local PostgreSQL database using *psycopg2 2.6* and *Python 2.7.8*. The connection settings and commands are the following:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
DATABASE_NAME = 'myappdatabase'
DATABASE_PORT = '5432'
DATABASE_USER = 'myappuser'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'secret'
DATABASE_TABLE = 'myappdata'

def _database_connection():
    conn_string = "host='{0}' dbname='{1}' port='{2}' user='{3}' \
        password='{4}'".format(HOST, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_PORT, \
        DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD)
    return psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

The script works without problems on machine one which has PostgreSQL 9.4 installed. The configuration in `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf` is not modified and looks like this, without comments:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I can also successfully connect to the same database using *pgAdmin III*.

## The problem

On a second machine with the same setup I cannot connect via the script. The following error occurs:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myappuser"
>   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myappuser"

The only **difference** between these two machines is the **database password**. So I changed it to a simple password - and boom, it works. So I changed it back to a complicated ... and it does **not** work again. The password is something like this:

> DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'zyx@12AA\w2'

So I thought: *"This is stupid. It must be my mistake."* So I set the database password on machine one to the same as on the second machine. And whoop the Python script also **fails**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The backslash in the password in this case is interpreted as escape character. Python would treat the backslash in `\w` as literal `\` even if it's not specified as a raw string because `\w` is not a valid escape sequence, but the underlying library also [parses escape sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING), therefore the backslash has to be escaped (doubled).

To avoid this, specify the connection parameters [as keyword arguments](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect) instead:

```
psycopg2.connect(host=HOST,
                 database=DATABASE_NAME,
                 port=DATABASE_PORT,
                 user=DATABASE_USER,
                 password=DATABASE_PASSWORD)
```

This avoids problems with special characters in passwords. Also a single quote chacacter in the password would break the connection string.

Comment: Thank you. I prepared the connection string as a way to print out the settings for debugging purpose.

Comment: Please note that "database" is now deprecated. Use "dbname" instead.

Comment: the password failing for me was uu7bl+Yu+0BhR#qN in postgres 15 with knex, there is no backslash nor single quotes, maybe it's the underlying library issue