# eclipse luna and postgres db 9.4 connection

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to connect postgres in eclipse. But I am getting below error after entering all details for jdbc connection:

```
Database:postgres
url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
user name:postgres
pass :postgres
```

jar file:D:\Workspace: postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc41

```
Ping failed:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:427)
    at
```

Comment: welcome to SO. please learn how to [ask a good question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. I wonder if you made any effort to resolve this. fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the password you provided for the `postgres` user is wrong.