# Postgres & Rails – FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

Newbie to Postgres, basic skills with Rails, so bear with me.

I will explain the process of how I got to where I am, in case I did anything wrong along the way.

#### **What I did.**

I created a Rails 5 project (using the actual Git repo) and, once it was created successfully, I found the default `gem sqlite3` in the **Gemfile**.

Now, I want to work with Postgres, so I turned `sqlite3` into `pg`, and ran `bundle install`. Worked perfectly, Rails didn't complain.

Then, I installed Postgres on my computer (using the latest OS X) and ran `createdb testDB`. It's an empty database.

Now, I have to configure the **database.yml** file. After going through a dozen of links and resources, I changed the file's contents to the following:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: testDB
  username: postgres
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port: 9057


development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
  database: someOtherDB
```

I am certain that the port number is correct, because I set it manually, and I can check that it's running using the command `netstat -na`. I get the following two lines:

```
tcp6       0      0  *.9057                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.9057                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Now, in order to change the password for *postgres* to ensure it's actually the cleverly secure string `password`, I ran the following commands:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

Opens up the `psql` prompt, then I run the command:

```
psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.

template1=# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'password';
```

Which returned:

```
ALTER ROLE
```

Yay! Password's changed! Now I can open up my first ever working Rails app with a Postgres backend!

#### **What I got.**

I run `bin/rails server`, and I get the following error:

[image: The error I get]

#### **Some more info that may be helpful.**

When I run the command `psql -l`, I get the following:

```
                                        List of databases
   Name    |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |       Access privileges       
-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 postgres  | myusername | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | myusername | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/myusername              +
           |              |          |             |             | myusername=CTc/myusername
 template1 | myusername | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/myusername              +
           |              |          |             |             | myusername=CTc/myusername
 test      | myusername | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 testDB    | myusername | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
(5 rows)
```

If I run `psql X` (where X is any of the databases listed above) followed by running the command `\du`, I get the following.

```
                               List of roles
  Role name   |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
--------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 myusername   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 postgres     | Superuser                                      | {}
```

I followed instructions on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres) and a few others to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here's [the content of `log/development.log`](http://pastebin.com/piCtuX43).

Comment: Is there anything in `log/development.log`?

Comment: On a side note - don't use the same database for tests and development. Your test suite should clean up the test database on every test run - while you might actually want to have some sample data in your development environment so that you can see what your app will look like with data.

Comment: Also this might sound pretty obvious but make sure you have restarted your rails server - `database.yml` is only read when the server starts - not per request.

Comment: Hi @hd1, here's the content. Also added it to the post. http://pastebin.com/piCtuX43

Comment: @max Thanks for the tip! I am restarting the server every time, still getting the same error.

Comment: One thing that might be worth a try is setting up a user with `CREATE ROLE rails_dev WITH LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD NULL` from psql and then change `username: 'rails_dev'` and comment out the `password:` in `database.yml`.

Comment: @max I'm not sure if it's Rails 5, but it won't take it without a password. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/1BOHeSJ.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94658/discussion-between-max-and-fares-k-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default login for rails is the current username logged in and a blank password.

Comment: Thanks for this, @hd1! After our discussion on chat, I took off the username and password attributes and it worked.