# psycopg2.connect failing with error 'connection refused' (Django app+db hosted on separate VMs)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, azure

I have a Django app where the app and database reside in two separate VMs. I use Azure. In trying to connect to a postgresql backend hosted in a separate Azure VM, I'm writing: `conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' host='dnsname'")`, where value of host was gotten off the Azure portal from here:

[image]

I have also tried the **Virtual IP address** above as the host. Both approaches fail and I get a connection error: `could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "myapp.cloudapp.net" (23.132.341.192) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` Please note that I changed the IP address when pasting the error here.

The Azure VM hosting the postgresql database has `port 5432` added to its **Endpoints**. Moreover, my app to which this postgresql backend belongs is a Django/Python app. My VMs have Ubuntu 14.04. In setting up postgresql, I ran the following installation commands on both app and database VMs separately:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install PostgreSQL postgresql-contrib`

`sudo apt-get install  postgresql-server-dev-all`

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

And even though *both* app and database VMs have all of the above installed in them, the **database itself** was only created in the latter VM. I didn't create a separate user; I instead did:
`sudo su postgres`

`psql -d postgres -U postgres`

And then

`CREATE DATABASE dbname;`

---

How do I fix the `psycopg2.connect` error? Ask for more information if needed.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried to access to this Postgres instance manually? That means from the django machine, can you manually connect to Postgres?

Comment: As in? I logged into the Django machine, and wrote `psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' host='dnsname'")` on the shell, in the bid to connect to the database in the other machine. If that's what you meant, yea I tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: no I mean opening a Postgres client and remotely connecting to the machine, Also try to ping and see if you can reach the Postgres machine from the Django machne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to separate PostgreSQL into another Azure VM, we need to configure several settings both on Azure VM side and your PostgreSQL service.

1, modify the `listen_addresses="*"` at `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf` ,to allow other client beside local to request your PostgreSQL service.

2, Add the following line as the first line of `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf`. It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

`# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

3, run command `sudo service postgresql restart` to restart the service

4, login Azure manage portal, add a request rule in Endpoints page of your VM, configure public port `5432` to private port `5432`:
[image]

Comment: No, you can only run postgresql server on the VM as the database tier

Comment: Hmm, anything else I need to do to ensure the two classic VMs can 'see' eachother, other than them being in the same resource group?

Comment: Azure will deploy VMs in some nearby data centers if they are in a same resource group, which will optimize network. I think you can first make sure that you can connect to your PostgreSQL on VM from local. if it works fine, then try the connection on another VM

Comment: Might the problem be that I'm not supplying a **password**? I tried to connect on `localhost`; ended up getting `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`. I then tried to connect on `localhost` without providing host (which forces psycopg2 to connect using a Unix socket in the same manner as `psql`, hence no password required), I successfully made the connection. Perhaps you could add this to your answer as well; meanwhile I'll test it further and accept the answer if it indeed turns out to untangle the tangle.

Comment: you can try to set the password to default user postgres, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres. Also you can get more information at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL