# Not able to connect to postgres on ec2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just installed PostgreSQL 9.2 server on an EC2 AMI instance. However I am not able to connect to it from the command prompt.

Moreover I see two directories in `/var/lib`: `pgsql9` and `pgsql92`. The data directory in pgsql92 is empty and hence it looks like pgsql9 is the one that is getting used.

```
[root@ip-172-31-56-103 etc]# psql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
[root@ip-172-31-56-103 etc]# sudo su - postgres
-bash-4.2$ psql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
-bash-4.2$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
-bash-4.2$
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all            all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host     all            all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Comment: Tried the solutions from link but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

To work out which PG install you are using: `ps -ef | grep pgsql`. You will see for sure which binary, data directory and conf file is being used to give you some comfort.

Have you changed the `pg_hba.conf` from the default? If so, did you reload it? Something like `sudo service postgresql reload` should do it, depending upon your OS.

You might want to change the IPv6 local connection to use `md5` as well.

Try adding `-h localhost` or `-h 127.0.0.1` to your `psql` command: e.g. `psql -h localhost -U postgres`.

Check your `postgres` password to be *doubly* / *triply* sure.

Otherwise, check out the specific docs for your OSs installation. Sometimes `apt` or `yum` repos do some additional security configuration for you.

Finally, worst case, change all the `pg_hba.conf` auth methods to `trust`, then restart the database, logon, change the `postgres` password, logout, change the auth methods to `md5`, reload and try to logon again.