# PSQLException: password-based authentication

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

Here is the Exception:when I run my testDao file, working on springs.Is there any path given to database in springs?

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:473)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:159)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:416)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:283)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.dao.java.TestDao.getConnection(TestDao.java:37)
    at com.test.dao.java.TestDao.getTest(TestDao.java:61)
    at com.test.main.java.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:33)
```

HERE is my >>testDao file where connection with postgresql is made

```
   @Component 
    public class TestDao {
    static PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection conn= null;

     /**
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException,FileNotFoundException,NullPointerException{


         if(conn==null)
         {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                       "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb?user=postgres & password=postgres");
                    conn.close();
        }
                catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
     }
         return conn;


    }

    /**
     * @param testId
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws NullPointerException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public Test getTest(int testId) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException  {

            conn = getConnection();
        try {

            conn = getConnection();
            ps =conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM testdb.testtab where id =?");
            ps.setInt(1, testId);
            Test test =null;
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                test = new Test(testId, rs.getString("name"));
            }

    return test;
        }
        finally
        {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }


    }
    }
```

HERE is my >>springNew.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd "

xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
<!-- <context-annotation-config/> -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.dao"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres). Did you try loggin in manually?

Comment: @TheLostMind-the database is already opened.

Comment: try using `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb", "postgres","postgres");`

Comment: @ankur-singhal - I tried then it gives org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "testdb" does not exist

Comment: @PalakChugh - Did you check if that DB exists

Comment: @ankur-singhal - Her code should work (Although I agree that she should have used the latter method

Comment: @TheLostMind-it does exist checked.

Comment: @PalakChugh - How did you check. Check the properties of the DB.

Comment: @TheLostMind-Issue is with environment variables

Comment: @PalakChugh - Please elaborate. What was the issue? (PS, also add an answer to help others who have the same issue :)

Comment: @TheLostMind-the classpath of environment variable was not set ..now I have done that still the issue is same and has not resolved :(

Comment: @PalakChugh - Do one thing. Create a simple java project and add postgres jar. Then use the same code in `main()` and see if it works

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got the issue and finally resolved it firstly schema was needed to be mentioned as below

```
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb?currentSchema=testdb&user=postgres&password=postgres");
```

Secondly I was closing the conn thus it was returning empty rs and was closing the connection before it could be used.

Comment: Thank god for this answer. Doing some PySpark + PostgreSQL work and specifying the schema explicitly in the string was the only thing that worked. Thank you!