# Vagrant postgres ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, vagrant

I have got the vagrant machine with Postgres on it. I need to connect with this database using some external tools (eg. pgmodeler, keetle).
So i start tunnel using:

```
ssh -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 vagrant@192.168.56.140 -i puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa
```

Then I try to login with command:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U postgres postgres
```

And I get an error:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I'm a little bit confused because it used to work, and now it doesn't. I've tried to set user password but it didn't work. Where should i look for a problem?

Comment: Why not forward ports using vagrant? https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Comment: OK. So I've tried your solution but problem still exists. I think there is problem in Postgres. Maybe in pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: It's a pg configuration issue. Show the pg_hba.conf of the vagrant machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Comment: @JakubKania Here is my pg_hba.conf file:
`local all postgres  ident `
`local all all  ident `
`host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 md5 `
`host all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 reject` 
`host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5 `
`host all all ::1/128 md5 `

Comment: @JakubKania the solution in the topic above doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `pg_hba.conf` file of your postgres server to tell postgres from where connections for which users are allowed. In debian-like distributions you'll find this file in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`.

When developing with vagrant i usually use the following entry in pg_hba.conf which **allows all users** to connect **from everywhere without a password**

```
# IPv4 connections from everywhere:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

**NEVER USE THIS LINE ON A PRODUCTION SERVER**

On top there is the following line in my Vagrantfile to forward the port

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    # more stuff
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5433, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
end
```

Do not forget to set the host_ip to localhost, otherwise postgres binds to all network interfaces of your local machine.

Comment: OK. I found the problem. Locally I have Postgres installed too. So i needed to switch it off and it works now. But can't I have it both?

Comment: Sure you can just change the host port  in Vagrantfile to e.g. 5433 as you did it with your tunnel.