# error: error: password authentication failed for user "electron_release_server_user"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I was messing around with this amazing Sails project [here](https://github.com/ArekSredzki/electron-release-server).

I managed to get it 100% functional on my Macbook Pro with little to no difficulty.

[Here's my fork](https://github.com/tylerl0706/electron-release-server).

Now I'm trying to get it working on an Azure Ubuntu 14.04 box and after running it with `npm start` which just calls `node app.js` I get this error:

```
Error creating a connection to Postgresql using the following settings:
{ host: 'localhost',
 port: 5432,
 schema: true,
 ssl: false,
 adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
 user: 'electron_release_server_user',
 password: '[redacted]',
 database: 'electron_release_server',
 identity: 'postgresql' }

* * *
Complete error details:
 { error: password authentication failed for user "electron_release_server_user"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/azureuser/electron-release-server/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/azureuser/electron-release-server/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/azureuser/electron-release-server/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:535:20)
 name: 'error',
 length: 117,
 severity: 'FATAL',
 code: '28P01',
 detail: undefined,
 hint: undefined,
 position: undefined,
 internalPosition: undefined,
 internalQuery: undefined,
 where: undefined,
 schema: undefined,
 table: undefined,
 column: undefined,
 dataType: undefined,
 constraint: undefined,
 file: 'auth.c',
 line: '285',
 routine: 'auth_failed' }
```

In my local.js I have:

```
connections: {
    postgresql: {
      adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'electron_release_server_user',
      password: '<SECRET>',
      database: 'electron_release_server'
    }
  },
```

This exact configuration worked on my local machine but now that it's on this Ubuntu VM... no luck.

Anyone? I need this in order to release a product!

Comment: `error: password authentication failed for user "electron_release_server_user"` looks clear to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it turned out to be my version of Node.

Node.js 6.0 just didn't seem to work. Once I downgraded to LTS, poof, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you.. U save my time.. Keep it up.

Comment: This solved it for me. I downgraded to 5.12.0 and it worked.

Comment: Any idea if this issue persists on Node 9.4.0 ?

Comment: Any idea if the issue exist on Node 8.11.3?

Comment: The issue still exists on Node.js 9, at least when using old versions of the pg library (necessary in my case for connecting to a PostgreSQL 8 server).  I used the npm version manager "n" to install a second installation at 5.12.0, and running my application with that 5.12.0 installation instead of Node.js 9 solved the issue.

Comment: using lts for version 8, 9, 10 got the same error, upgrading nodejs cancelled :))

Answer (score 2):

Per my experience, the issue belongs to the scope of `Client Authentication` problems that you can refer to the Postgres document to know it, please see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/client-authentication-problems.html.

The usual solution is that checking or changing the password for the specified user via the Postgres command `ALTER USER`, please see the document http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alteruser.html.

There is an exsiting SO thread which you can refer to, please see [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've seen that SO thread and unfortunately the suggestions did not solve my issue. That's why I posted this question hopping that this was a Sails issue. I attempted to connect to that database using:

`psql -U electron_release_server_user -h localhost electron_release_server`

I was prompted for the password, I put it in, and it worked. I was successfully connected to the database: `electron_release_server=>` is my prompt.