# python manage.py migrate error

Tags: django, migrate, manage.py

I am learning Django and was trying to migrate manage.py using the command 
`python manage.py migrate`. But what happened is

```
(venv) Kaustubhs-MacBook-Pro-2:crmeasy kaustubhmundra$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 179, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.get_table_list(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 165, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 138, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 134, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Django/crmeasy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Answer (score 2):

You should add correct password of **postgres** user in *settings.py* as it says  `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Haha..that was noobish of me :P

Answer (score 0):

Set a password for `postgres`

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

In psql terminal

```
\password postgres
```

Set the password and add it into your `settings.py` file