# Ruby on Rails Authentication Error for postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, authentication

I have created Postgresql database locally. 
[Postgre database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd1H7.png)

And here is my database.yml file.
default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog
  username: postgres
  password: Naruto1994.

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog
  username: postgres
  password: Naruto1994.

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog
  username: postgres
  password: Naruto1994.
```

I have made sure to enter correct password but I am still getting this error.

[Error in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQWiX.png)

Comment: Try removing the dot from password? Also, how do You create Your db? Have You actually set this password on psql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may add localhost, and makesure if you have password with dot or no dot (Naruto1994), and my suggestion split database name between each environment (development, test and production)

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myrubyblog_development
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: Naruto1994.  
  pool: 5

test: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: myrubyblog_test
  username: postgres
  password: Naruto1994.  
  pool: 5

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myrubyblog_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: #env_variable
  password: #env_variable
```

Answer (score 3):

Messages like this indicate that you contacted the server, and it is willing to talk to you, but not until you pass the authorization method specified in the pg_hba.conf file.

Try this:

```
// set new password for user "postgres"
$sudo su postgres -c 'psql --username=postgres'
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';
//change pg_hba.conf
local all postgres md5
```

then restart postgres.

This article might help you: [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `host: localhost` to each env. e.g.

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: Naruto1994.
```