# Why postgresql on mac asks me for password after fresh install?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed `postgresql` on a Macbook with `brew install postgresql`. Then I try to `psql`, but it requires password and then show `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<myname>"`.

I have not set up anything, and inputting my mac password does nothing. What should I do now?

Comment: hm. for localhost it should by default use peer authentication, not md5... what's in `pg_hba.conf`?..  (`sudo find / -name pg_hba.conf`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So your username probably does not exist, as the default username that ships with the db is `postgres`.

Further, I was prevented from the submission of an empty password,  which is blank by default for the `postgres` user.

You might try

```
cd ~/
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';"
Password: YOUR_LOGIN_PWD_HERE (required for sudo)
```

and then to use

```
psql -U postgres
password: postgres
```

I'm not 100% sure of which SO answer I got this from, perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13796578/3100284). Hope this helps.

Comment: How will this work? for changing the password it will first ask the existing password...

Comment: In my case, it asked for password with the 2nd command, I fixed it by updating/reseting my postgres user, open System Preference->User Groups->PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks aldrien that is really the easiest way, all the other Stack overflow advice was useless. To anyone else, the section is "Users and Groups" in System preferences.

Answer (score 8):

The above did not work for me.
The below steps worked for me:

Step 1: Uninstall Postgres using the following steps:

```
sudo /Library/PostgreSQL/10/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall-postgresql
```

PS: my postgres version is 10

Step 2: Remove Postgresql user

```
System Preference > userse & Groups > Unlock > remove postgresql user by clicking "-"
```

Step 3: Remove existing databases

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres/*
```

Step 4: Install and Start Postgres using brew

```
brew update
brew install postgresql
brew services start postgresql
```

Step 5: Create database

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

You can start accessing postgres

```
psql -h localhost -d postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Pramida almost worked for me... the difference is I was using 9.6 Postgres.

So I ran:

> sudo
>   /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh

and somehow that got rid of my username and almost all of postgres user.  *I think*

I then blew away the directory

> sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6

And then I installed using brew above.

Answer (score 0):

in my case macboook big sur v 11 you should create `/var/postgresql@12` in `Mackbook/usr/local`
and open terminal in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.8/bin and run

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.8/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@12`
then run in terminal

```
 echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.8/bin:$PATH"'  >> ~/.zshrc
```

then

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgres
```

and enjoy creating user

Answer (score 0):

As aldrien.h mentioned in a comment, what worked for me was to simply go to System Preferences > Users & Groups and manually change the password of the PostgreSQL user.

Answer (score -1):

rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8

Comment: Probably you should explain why this line answers the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28337527)