# Why does `psql postgres` say I have the wrong password?

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Mac. I installed postgres with `brew postgresql`.

When I type in `psql postgres`, it serves

`Password for user [myuser]:`

And when I give it the password, it says

`psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "[myuser]"`

But I know that I'm giving it the right password.

Comment: `I know that I'm giving it the right password`: Do you, though? What I do in cases like this is, type the password in a plaintext editor, then select and copy it, and paste it in the password prompt. Not the most elegant solution, but it should work. That way you can rule out typos.

Comment: Yup, I am absolutely certain it is the right password.

Comment: The value it has for [myuser] is the name of my Mac user. It's the right password for my Mac user.

Comment: Try typing `psql postgres postgres`

Comment: It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781471/why-postgresql-on-mac-asks-me-for-password-after-fresh-install) that the default credentials are username `postgres`, password `postgres`.

Comment: That did it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turns out when I run psql shell it runs version 12 by default and when I went to the file location (right click on the psql shell and view location) I went to the version 13 (the version that I installed, replace it with the version that you installed) file and run psql shell and the password worked, I hope this helps.