# Change postgres username from current username to 'postgres'?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to connect to postgres and am getting the `password authentication failed for user <myusername>`

I have Postico installed and can connect to a database without a password so long as my username is `postgres`. I used the solution found here to get this to work.

[Why postgresql on mac asks me for password after fresh install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781471/why-postgresql-on-mac-asks-me-for-password-after-fresh-install)

However, in my visual studio code terminal, when I run psql, it's still asking for my password for my username rather than password for 'postgres' user.

How do I change the default user to connect to?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you can specify a different username for `psql` using the `-U` parameter

So if you run:

```
psql -U postgres ...
```

The connection will be made with the superuser. You will still need to provide a password if password authentication is configured.