# Got "password authentication failed for user" but in pgAdmin 3 its working

Tags: laravel, postgresql, pgadmin

Why I can open the database from pgAdmin 3 but when I tried it on laravel, it doesn't working?

It Gives me this error

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "khrisna" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "khrisna"

I already tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres) by adding my own postgresql user

[image]

Here is the proof that my pgAdmin accept my user and password, I even added new "server" to make sure that my credentials are correct

[image]

So why in the laravel it says it wrong? Here is my `.env` file

[image]

**EDITED:**

I just realized, that I can run `php artisan migrate` without problems, so why the only problem is to access the database? I already hit the wall and don't know what to do or even I don't know what kind of keywords I need to type into google to get the answer.

Comment: Have u checked the port number

Comment: try port 5433 in .env

Comment: @Jigs1212 Yes, I already checked the port number, you can see it on pgAdmin screenshot, that `5432` is working

Comment: Indeed it's not the port. "Password authentication failed" is an error from the postgresql server. So you actually have a connection to the database server but it is not letting you proceed further because something isn't right with the username password combination.

Comment: @Eelke yeah that's true, but the problem is it's not working only on laravel, as you can see I can connect to my postgresql server without problem on pgAdmin, that's why I don't know why is this happening

Comment: @Eelke hi, it turns out I can run `php artisan migrate` without any errors, so why it's only happened when I tried to get data from the database?

Comment: Post the relevant code you use for retrieving data.

Comment: @Eelke I already did that, I already change the user password several times, this is the file content `localhost:5432:*:postgres:rootroot`, I changed the owner of the database to the default one, and I already change  it on `.env` file as well. but it's still the same error I got

Comment: @Eelke It's the default code, from login and register laravel features `php artisan make:auth`, and I haven't change anything

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya did you figure this out? I've ran into the same issue. Postico has no issues connection. When I login to psql via terminal, it asks for a password and has no problem connecting. Only Laravel can't seem to use the password correctly.

Comment: @SegFaultDev sorry, i can’t figure this out, so I use the mysql instead. Maybe there’s a problem with laravel 5.6, maybe you can try using laravel 5.7.*?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem because I was using Homestead, so the localhost address was pointing to the virtual machine, not my computer. Changing the IP address to MY IP address worked. Or else just use the Laravel default who's user name is homestead and password is secret. It accesses Postres as a local instance on the virtual machine