# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I am using Windows 10 and have just installed PostgreSQL 10.4.
Now my superuser is postgres and I have to create a new user. I used the following command on cmd :-

`psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE gautam LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;" mydb`

and the error is

`C:\Users\Gautam Jajoo>psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "C:\Users\Gautam Jajoo\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf"`

Can anyone tell the possible solution for it !!

Answer (score 0):

Add the -W parameter to be prompted for password

```
psql -U postgres -c -W "CREATE ROLE gautam LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;"
```

and you can use http://cmder.net to have cmd in windows

Comment: Added -W parameter also, not working. result is same

Comment: download cmder 
run it and do sudo
then run: "su postgres"
then run: "psql"
that will log you in as postgres

Comment: I have done the same. It is asking for password and I entered the password but getting the error psql: `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres " `

Comment: it seems to me that the user has a white space at the end

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres