# How do you connect to a localhost PostgreSQL Database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm getting an authorization error when trying to connect to my postgres database through localhost. I can log in fine with `sudo -u postgres psql`. When trying to connect through my Express application (using both Sequelize and node-postgres) I get an error.

error:

```
error: password authentication failed for user: "postgres"
```

.env:

```
PGUSER="postgres"
PGHOST=""
PGPASSWORD=""
PGDATABASE=""
PGPORT=""
```

sequelize config:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/test', { ... });
```

I've edited my pg_hba.conf file, as well to accept all localhost connections with:

```
local all all _BLANK_ trust
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Comment: Did you reload PostgreSQL?

Comment: Did you also run your nodejs application with `sudo -u postgres`?

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL has been restarted with both `sudo systemctl restart postgres.service` and another restart command that I can't remember right now.

Comment: @Bauke THAT WORKED! Thank you, specifically the second answer. Sorry I hadn't seen that question before.