# PostgreSQL: password authentication is failing, but the password is correct

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm coding a simple "connect to db" program in Node.js using the `pg` module.

Until yesterday, everything was working fine, but now for some reason this error appears:

> error: password authentication failed for user "ezert"

I don't understand what is going on, because I know the password used in the script is correct.

Full code:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg'); // quando definido entre parêntesis, declara-se que se trata de um contrutor

let connectionURL = 'postgresql://ezert:<MY PASSWORD>@localhost:5432/mydb';

const client = new Client({
    connectionURL: connectionURL
});

client.connect();

client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table", function (err, result) {

    if (err) {

        console.log('[ERROR]:\n' + err);
        return;

    }

    console.log('[RESULT]:');
    console.log(result.rows);
    return;

});
```

Comment: are you able to connect using any tool like SQL workbench?

Comment: You will find a more complete message in the PostgreSQL server's log file.

Comment: @SandeepPatel I use DBeaver and it executes this exact same query with no problem...

Comment: are u using any special character in password? If so that could be a problem. you can also try altering password `sudo -u ezert psql -c "ALTER USER ezert PASSWORD 'newpassword';"

Comment: @SandeepPatel I'm just using numbers.

Comment: @SandeepPatel I already have tried to alter my password, but the problem persists...

Comment: I've fixed it thanks to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/24680845#24680845

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with PostgreSQL, not with Node.js.

To solve it:

1. Edit the following file: `/etc/postgresql/YOUR_PG_VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf`
2. Change all authentication methods to trust.
3. Change the Unix password for `postgres` user.
4. Restart your server.
5. Login with `psql -h localhost -U postgres`, using the password you chose at (3).
6. Now you can reset the `pg_hba.conf` file to the default values, if you want.