# I'm having a problem with an elastic bean stalk setup on AWS linux 2. It's a laravel App with Postgres as the DB. Password auth failed for user

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a laravel App on elastic beanstalk on AWS. And I am using Postgres as the DB. It is an AWS linux 2.

When I try connecting even local to the db I get this error.

I tried modifying the db's inbound rules, still not working.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:
> password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL:  password
> authentication failed for user "postgres" (SQL: select count(*) as
> aggregate from "user" where "phoneNumber" = +1111111111111111) in file
> /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
> on line 692

Comment: Probably it's a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['password authentication failed for user "postgres"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If your DB is a Managed PostgreSQL on AWS RDS

Then you may want to reset password of the `postgres` user.

As per [RDS manual](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/)

> To modify the master user password, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the [Amazon RDS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/).
> 2. Select **Databases**.
> 3. Select the RDS DB instance, and then choose **Modify**.
>    **Note:** If you use Aurora, expand the cluster, and choose the instance that you want to modify. Then, choose **Modify**.
> 4. Enter the master user password you want to use in the **New Master Password** field.
>    **Note**: The password change is asynchronous, and applies as soon as possible. This change ignores the **Apply Immediately** setting.
> 5. Choose **Continue**, and then choose **Modify DB Instance**.
>
> The **Status** field for your RDS DB instance on the RDS dashboard changes to **resetting-master-credentials**. When the modification is complete, the **Status** column changes to **Available**. You can also modify an RDS DB instance using the [Amazon RDS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html) or the [AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html).

## If your DB is self-deployed to the `AWS EC2` instance

Then you may want to enable password-based authentication of the `postgres` user. It's disabled by default for new DB instances.

1. Find the `pg_hba.conf` file
   To find the pg_hba.conf file on your server, you can look in the PostgreSQL configuration directory.
   E.g.:

```
find /etc/postgresql/ -name pg_hba.conf
```

2. Then open found file in your `${EDITOR}`
3. To allow md5 password authentication for any connections coming from the local 192.168.0.0/24 network, add a line like this:

```
# TYPE    DATABASE    USER        ADDRESS         METHOD  OPTIONS
host      all         all         192.0.0.0/24    md5
```

4. And then [restart](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) PostgreSQL:

```
sudo pgctl restart
```

Answer (score 1):

you're right *@Yasen*, thanks man.

changing the password worked

it crossed my mind earlier but some how I just kept creating new db instances with the same password and it kept failing.

**anyways, the underlying issue was the password contained a '#' and '#' in laravel and hence php means comment;
so, somehow it was affecting the validation process.**