# Reset postgres user password?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have vagrant installed and I cannot sign in to the database through pgAdmin. When I attempt to access in terminal I receive the following error:
  [image]

How can I either reset the password or create a new user via command line or through pgAdmin?

Comment: try `psql -d postgres -U postgres` - if you have peer or trust for cocket it won't ask for password

Comment: unfortunately no, peer authentication error

Comment: After realizing that the application would run, I located the password in the application's config files. I'd still like to know how though.

Comment: `sudo su - postgres` and then `psql -d postgres -U postgres`?.. otherwise you will need to change `hba.conf` allowing `local all all trust` to login passwordless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the `postgres` password. That account is for user admin work. It should stay locked.

[*See my notes on the `postgres` user and how to set up here.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172588/124486)