# Not sure if I have PostgreSQL installed on my Mac properly for creating Flask web app

Tags: postgresql, flask, superuser

I installed PosgreSQL 10.5 on a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 using Homebrew by following [this tutorial.](https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb) After installation, I ran **=# \du** to view all users. I saw the user with my Mac's name that the tutorial says PostgreSQL creates during installation, but the "postgres" default user was not created (or at least did not appear).

**My Main Issue is...**

I need to login to PostgreSQL 'at the root', and I either do not understand exactly what that means, or something is wrong. In following the very first steps from the [PostgreSQL wiki's First Steps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps) documentation, it says to...

First connect/login as root:

```
 # su - postgres
 $ psql
 psql (9.6.0)
 Type "help" for help.
```

But when I open a terminal window and type in `su - postgres` it asks for a password. I've typed in every password I could possibly have given that role, and it just says `su: Sorry`.

I did some research and tried to change the password by doing this:

`postgres=# \password postgres`.

That prompted me to enter a password twice, and it seemed to work. But, when I go back and run: `su - postgres`, it just gives me the same `su: sorry`.

So I tried typing in: `psql postgres`. This at least changed the $ to postgres=#, which tells me that I am at the PostgreSQL command line, and then the same: `su: postgres`, but that just changed the (=) sign to a (-), so now it changed to: `postgres-#`

I thought that maybe this meant that I was "logged into PostgreSQL at the root, but then I ran the following:

```
postgres=# su - postgres
postgres-# CREATE SCHEMA test
postgres-# CREATE USER tester PASSWORD 'P@ssword1'
postgres-# GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA test TO tester
postgres-# \q
```

...and none of that worked. It did not create a user or a schema.

**History...**

- I've installed/uninstalled PostgreSQL on this Mac several times
  in the past for testing
- I've also installed/uninstalled pdAdmin for various reasons

It is highly possible that I did something in all of that shuffle that brought about this issue with the 'postgres' role not being created during this Homebrew instal. So, I did read through the rest of that tutorial and I did type in `$ createuser postgres` and that did seem to create the 'postgres' role. I tried to use `ALTER ROLE` to give that role `Create DB` but I never could get it to work using the command line, so I just opened pgAdmin, saw the role, granted it Create DB, and then back in command line ran `=# \du` again, and `Create DB` did appear next to the 'postgres' role I'd created. I added everything in pgAdmin, and now it looks like this.

```
                                      List of roles
   Role name    |                         Attributes                         | Member of
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 MyMacsNameHere | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 postgres       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication             | {}
```

**My end goal...**

I am trying to follow along with [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=addnlzdSQs4) about creating a Flask web application from scratch. In the YouTube tutorial, he uses MySQL, but I want to use PostgreSQL. Needless to say, I am up against a learning curve.

Comment: You don't need to use the **OS-user** postgres. You can use the **Postgres-user** postgres by starting psql with the -U flag: `psql -U postgres mydbname` (if you don't use the -U flag, psql assumes that your OS-username is also your DB-username)

Comment: This is AWESOME! So when I type: `psql -U postgres myflaskapp` that is saying: [ <command line client> `psql` ]... login as [ <role = 'postgres' > ] `-U postgres`... into the database named: `myflaskapp`.  Correct? 
Does this mean that if I log into PostgreSQL, by just typing in: `psql -U postgress`, then I am "logged in at the root?"

Comment: Two things: 1)normally you should **not** connect to the DBMS using the 'postgres' username 2) CREATE SCHEMA creates a schema (!!) in the database that you are currently connected to. (MYSQL is different in this aspect, IIRC)

Comment: Summary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172588/905902