# How to switch user in PostgreSQL? I mean login as another existed user in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to switch user just like I do in MySQL and MariaDB:
Just like in MySQL/MariaDB CLI cmd is:

```
mysql> SYSTEM MySQL -u <user_name> -p ;
Enter Password: *********
Welcome to MySQL Monitor. ...
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58466025/6244324

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the `psql` cli or the general [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-role.html)?

Comment: `\connect user_name`?

Comment: Actually it would be ```\connect  -  user_name```. The first argument to \connect is the database name. Using ```-``` maintains the existing database.