# Createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL: role "tom" does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to set up Postgres for the first time, and I need to create a user with permissions to read and create databases. However, when I use:

```
createuser username
```

in my terminal I get the following message:

> createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "tom" does not exist

Tom is my Ubuntu user account that I'm logged into right now. I'm trying to create a username of "postgres" then do a `psql -U psql template1` so I can create a database and assign an owner to it for my Rails app.

Comment: Are you really trying to create a 'postgres' user? Or just a user for your Rails app? Normally the 'postgres' user already exists and the problem is just connecting to it in order to do what you need.

Answer (score 161):

You mentioned Ubuntu so I'm going to guess you installed the PostgreSQL packages from Ubuntu through apt.

If so, the `postgres` PostgreSQL user account already exists and is configured to be accessible via `peer` authentication for unix sockets in `pg_hba.conf`. You get to it by running commands as the `postgres` unix user, eg:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser owning_user
sudo -u postgres createdb -O owning_user dbname
```

This is all in the [Ubuntu PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) documentation that's the first Google hit for "Ubuntu PostgreSQL" and is covered in numerous Stack Overflow questions.

*(You've made this question a lot harder to answer by omitting details like the OS and version you're on, how you installed PostgreSQL, etc.)*

Comment: well after  creating owning_user, How do yo connect with this user? I mean to connect default user i use , 
 sudo -u postgres psql postgres .
same way how to connect owning_user?

Comment: Three options. (a) Set a password for that user and edit `pg_hba.conf` to use `md5` auth for that user (see the manual); (b) Create an OS user by the same name and keep on using `peer` auth; or (c) more advanced, create a `pg_ident.conf` mapping to allow your OS user to log in as the new user.

Answer (score 109):

[See git gist with instructions here](https://gist.github.com/ekumachidi/aac9316496fb2ca84dcef00920fede9b)

Run this:

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
```

OR

```
psql -U postgres
```

in your terminal to get into postgres

> **NB: If you're on a Mac and both of the commands above failed jump to the section about Mac below**

```
postgres=#
```

Run

```
CREATE USER new_username;
```

Note: Replace new_username with the user you want to create, in your case that will be tom.

```
postgres=# CREATE USER new_username;
CREATE ROLE
```

Since you want that user to be able to create a DB, you need to alter the role to superuser

```
postgres=# ALTER USER new_username SUPERUSER CREATEDB;
ALTER ROLE
```

To confirm, everything was successful,

```
postgres=# \du
                         List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
new_username     | Superuser, Create DB                           | {}
postgres         | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
root             | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}

postgres=#
```

**Update/Modification (For Mac):**

I recently encountered a similar error on my Mac:

`psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

This was because my installation was setup with a database superuser whose role name is the same as your login (short) name.

But some linux scripts assume the superuser has the traditional role name of `postgres`

**How did I resolve this?**

If you installed with `homebrew` run:

`/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres`

> If you're using a specific version of postgres, say `10.5` then run:

`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/bin/createuser -s postgres`

OR:

`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/bin/createuser -s new_username`

OR:

`/usr/local/opt/postgresql@11/bin/createuser -s postgres`

> If you installed with `postgres.app` for Mac run:

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10.5/bin/createuser -s postgres`

P.S: replace 10.5 with your PostgreSQL version

Comment: This worked to get into postgres: `psql -U postgres`

Comment: In case someone faces the same issue. The capital words like CREATE USER or ALTER USER must (!) be capital in psql, unlike in any database IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a bug with a backup with this

Answer (score 32):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s tom
```

this should help you as this will happen if the administrator has not created a PostgreSQL user account for you. It could also be that you were assigned a PostgreSQL user name that is different from your operating system user name, in that case you need to use the -U switch.

Answer (score 7):

Your error is posted in the official documentation. You can [read this article](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-createdb.html).

I have copied the reason for you (and hyperlinked the URLs) from that article:

> This will happen if the administrator has not created a PostgreSQL user account for you. (PostgreSQL user accounts are distinct from operating system user accounts.) If you are the administrator, see [Chapter 20](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/user-manag.html) for help creating accounts. You will need to become the operating system user under which PostgreSQL was installed (usually postgres) to create the first user account. It could also be that you were assigned a PostgreSQL user name that is different from your operating system user name; in that case you need to use the -U switch or set the PGUSER environment variable to specify your PostgreSQL user name

For your purposes, you can do:

1) Create a PostgreSQL user account:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser tom -d -P
```

(the `-P` option to set a password; the `-d` option for allowing the creation of database for your username 'tom'. Note that 'tom' is your operating system username. That way, you can execute PostgreSQL commands without `sudo`ing.)

2) Now you should be able to execute `createdb` and other PostgreSQL commands.

Answer (score 7):

1- Login as default PostgreSQL user (postgres)

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

2- As postgres user. Add a new database user using the `createuser` command

```
[postgres]$ createuser --interactive
```

3-exit

```
[postgres]$ exit
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the authentication method (ident) and mess with *pg_hba.conf* use this:

First login as the default user

```
 sudo su - postgres
```

then access psql and create a user with the same name as the one you are login in

```
postgres=# CREATE USER userOS WITH PASSWORD 'garbage' CREATEDB;
```

you can verify your user with the corresponding roles with

```
postgres=#  \du
```

Afer this you can create your database and verify it with

```
psql -d dbName
\l
\q
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i just do this

sudo su - postgres

createuser odoo -U postgres -dRSP  #P for password
    (**odoo** or **user name** that you want o give the postgres access)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows use:

`C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin>createuser -U postgres --pwprompt <USER>`

Add `--superuser` or `--createdb` as appropriate.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html for further options.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, you can activate SUPERUSER to enable to create databases like this:

1. Go to terminal/shell
2. Enter inside postgres using
   `sudo -u postgres -i`

Now your terminal will be like "postgres@anish-Latitude-E7450:~$"

3. Enter postgres terminal using
   `psql`

Now your terminal will be like "postgres=#"

4. Enter `alter user [postgres_user_name]  createdb;`

Now the user will be having access to create db.

5. Exit psql using '\q'
6. Logout postgres using `exit`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -3):

You need to first run initdb. It will create the database cluster and the initial setup

See [How to configure postgresql for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471571/how-to-configure-postgresql-for-the-first-time) and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-initdb.html

Comment: This is completely incorrect. If the user hadn't run `initdb` they wouldn't have a database server running and accepting connections in order to produce the error message reported. Please remove this misleading answer. (BTW, in future, please link to /docs/current/static/ to avoid stale links accumulating)