# createdb: database creation failed: ERROR: permission denied to create database

Tags: database, postgresql, root, roles, permission-denied

I'm pretty much confused about **root user**,**super user**,**user** and **permissions**! I am not able to create a database inside user "athleticu". Following are the commands I used:-

```
athleticu@ip-172-30-4-103:/home/ubuntu$ createdb -T template0 simple_db1
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
athleticu@ip-172-30-4-103:/home/ubuntu$ sudo createdb -T template0 simple_db1
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-30-4-103
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Please somebody clarify my doubts and tell me what should I write!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right Address for the server: "unable to resolve host up-172-30-4-103"?

Comment: You need to connect using the postgres super user. Typically that is `postgres`. Try `createdb -U postgres ....`

Comment: Actually I am connecting to an instance of AWS machine using:-  `sudo ssh -i "athleticu-test-keypair.pem" ubuntu@52.91.xxx.xxx` and then it's get like this : `ubuntu@ip-172-30-4-103:~$ `  @patrick

Comment: Do you mean I should first login into `postgres` user and then I should login into `athleticu`? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: [Try this Solution worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37500607/7059556)

Answer (score 103):

Hey I have already solved this. What you have to do is to first login as postgres user as follows:

```
$ su postgres

$ psql

postgres=# alter user athleticu createdb;
ALTER ROLE
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Couldn't get into `postgres` without a password, but elevating to root allowed me to: `sudo su postgres`

Comment: Note that as of postgresql 8.1, "`ALTER USER` is now an alias for `ALTER ROLE`".

Answer (score 47):

Type `\du` in psql and you will see a list of all the registered users and what type of privileges each one has. 
In order to grant privileges to the user which is logged in (eg 'user1'), I had to sign out and log in using one of the superuser roles in that list (eg. 'user2'), using the following command:

```
    psql -U 'user2' -h localhost 'database2'
```

where 'database2' is the name of the one that specific superuser 'user2' has privileges to.
Once you are logged in as a superuser, you can grant privileges to 'user1' by:

```
    ALTER ROLE user1 WITH CREATEDB
```

or

```
    ALTER ROLE user1 WITH SUPERUSER
```

Then sign in again as user1, who is now a superuser.

This [blog](https://jrcorner.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/troubleshooting-postgres-error-permission-denied-to-create-db/) was helpful as well as this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql).

Comment: Works well. In my case (version 10.17) I had to write `ALTER ROLE "user1" WITH CREATEDB;` — note quotation marks and semicolon.

Answer (score 20):

Currently, this worked for me:

```
sudo su postgres
psql

ALTER USER username WITH CREATEDB;
\q

exit
```

Sources: [alter role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-alterrole.html), [alter user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-alteruser.html)

Answer (score 11):

The **root user** is an account on the system independent from Postgres. There is only one root user.

A **superuser** is an account in Postgres with access to everything. There may be many superusers.

System accounts and Postgres accounts are different things, although unless you specify a Postgres username when you connect to the database (through utilities like `psql`, `createdb`, `dropdb`, or otherwise), it will use the current system user's name in hopes that there is a corresponding Postgres account with the same name. The **root user** does not, by default, have a corresponding account in Postgres.

When you install Postgres on *nix, it creates both a **superuser** named `postgres` and a system user named `postgres`.

Therefore, when you need to do something with Postgres as the built-in superuser, you have two options:

1. You may `sudo su - postgres` to become the `postgres` **system user** and execute your command (`createdb`, `psql`, etc). Because the system user has the same name as the database superuser, your command will connect as the appropriate account.
2. You may specify the username to execute as with the `-U` switch, eg `psql -U postgres ...`.

Depending on your Postgres server's authentication settings, you may be required to enter a password with either or both connection methods.

Comment: hey thanks a lot! `When you install Postgres on *nix` - what is meant by `*nix` in your comment? does it mean Unix/Linux ? and about using postgres on ubuntu? Please clarify a little more! @dmfay

Comment: *nix refers to any operating system derived from or related to Unix, including the various Linux distributions (of which Ubuntu is one), the BSDs, and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do when you have fresh installation of PostgreSQL is create your user with some rights (see [createuser documentation](https://docs.postgresql.fr/8.2/app-createuser.html)):

```
my-user> sudo su - postgres -c "createuser <my-user> --createdb"
```

This will allow `my-user` to create DBs just like so:

```
my-user> createdb <my-db>
```

If you want the `my-user` to be able to do anything just use the `--superuser` flag instead:

```
my-user> sudo su - postgres -c "createuser <my-user> --superuser"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I found out that the reason was that I was trying to create a database outside of `psql` as a user which did not exist for postgresql. I found out about it and solved it by taking the following steps:

1. In my terminal I logged in as `postgres` user (*the root user by default for postgresql*) by typing `sudo -u postgres psql`
2. While inside the `psql` I typed `\du` to see all users and their privileges. I found out that I had only one user (*the postgres one*) and I had to create another superuser which had the same username as my Linux user (george)
3. I typed (still inside `psql`) `CREATE USER george SUPERUSER;` and this way I created a new super user called george.
4. I exited `psql` (by typing `\q`) and I was now able from outside `psql`, meaning from my terminal, to run `created db <database name>` with no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Error ?** You are trying to perform database actions( Creating Database, creating Roles) using a user that doesn't have the permission for those types of actions you are trying to perform.

**solution ?** Simply login to your database on the command line, i.e for PostgreSQL one will use "*sudo -u postgres psql*", then confirm that users specific assigned roles using the command "*\du*", most probably he/she doesn't have the necessary permissions to perform the actions you wanted. Then simply assign the roles you want the user to perform ,i.e create Database or simply make user "Superuser" by following along(https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-change-a-user-to-superuser-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create the user(role) `john` with `CREATEDB` privilege or add `CREATEROLE` privilege to the user(role) `john` as shown below. *You probably need to log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`) and you can omit `WITH` which is optional:

```sql
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'apple' CREATEDB;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH CREATEDB;
```

Then, you can create and drop `orange` database by logging in with `john` as shown below. *Be careful, there is the restriction to add some privileges:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE orange;
```

```sql
DROP DATABASE orange;
```