# Create tables on heroku postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Rest Api to heroku. This API uses postgres as database, and so I need to deploy also it. So, I went to the heroku site, created the application, added the specific postgres database. At this point, I need to create tables in the database. So, I opened up the terminal, and wrote the following command, to connect to the database

`psql --host=[HOSTNAME] --port=5432 --username=[USERNAME] --password --dbname=[DBNAME]`

Then, I typed the given password and at that point I was able to enter the database, because the `\dt` command showed that there weren't any relation. At this point I need to create my database and tables, so I tryied to write `CREATE DATABASE db;`, but it gave me the following error: `ERROR:  permission denied to create database`. This should be because I am not a high permission user, but I am not able to change that, even if I spent a lot of time searching for solution on youtube and in other stackoverflow questions.

So, I found another possible solution, that was typing in the CMD the following code:
`heroku pg:psql --app mad4feltre < database.sql`, that should put all the code that is in the SQL file in the database, but the terminal gives an error due to the `<` character, that  is reserved to future uses. Here is the error itself:

```
+ heroku pg:psql --app mad4feltre < database.sql
+                                 ~
Operator'<' reserved for future uses.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

I would like to know how to insert the database and the table in my postgres database. If one of the two possibilities can be fixed, it would be a great thing.

Here is the video and the post that I followed the most:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80oty2v4HsE

[createdb: database creation failed: ERROR: permission denied to create database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734650/createdb-database-creation-failed-error-permission-denied-to-create-database)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

- First, you cannot create databases using PostgreSQL commands on Heroku.

  But that's okay: when you provisioned your Heroku Postgres add-on, Heroku created a database for you. You are already connected to it via the `--dbname=[DBNAME]` argument.

  After connecting, you can start running queries right away.
- You appear to be using PowerShell. Most of Heroku's documentation uses Unix-style shell commands that may not work on PowerShell.

  In this case, the command is trying to use the contents of the `database.sql` file as standard input to the `heroku pg:psql` command. That [works a bit differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11447598/354577) on PowerShell.

  Try this instead:

  ```
  Get-Content database.sql | heroku pg:psql --app mad4feltre
  ```