# How to add Postgres on Mac OS with MAMP to PATH?

Tags: postgresql, macos, environment-variables, mamp

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/mac-os-development-environment/postgres-on-max-os-x-with-mamp) on how to run *Postgres on MAC OS X with MAMP*. But I can't seem to add PostgreSQL to my PATH variable. When I run `export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin"` I get this error:

> prompt_context:13: command not found: whoami
>   
> prompt_background_jobs:1: command not found: wc
>   
> prompt_background_jobs:2: command not found: awk

Here's exactly what I did:

- I downloaded PostgreSQL 11.2 from [Enterprise DB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#osx)
- I installed it using the installer:

  - username: postgres
  - password: postgres
  - port: 5433

The PostgreSQL folder can now be found here: `/Library/PostgreSQL`. Inside there's a folder called `11`. Inside `/Library/PostgreSQL/11` I can see the `bin` folder and `data` folder.

There's another folder inside my `Applications` folder called `PostgreSQL 11`. Here I can see a `Documentation` folder and some other programs I believe:

- Application Stack Builder
- pgAdmin 4
- Reload Configuration
- SQL Shell (psql)

The following error appears when I ignore setting the `PATH` variable and run `su postgres`:

> su: Sorry

or `sudo postgres`:

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
>   
> The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
>   
> possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
>   
> more information on how to properly start the server

Also, running `psql` gives me this error, because PostgreSQL is not included in my environmental variables:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   
>    Is the server running locally and accepting
>   
>    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.**5432**"?

Note: this error asks if the server is accepting Unix domain socket with a port 5432, while I installed PostgreSQL on port 5433, what's up with that? Moving to `/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin` with `cd` and running `sudo ./psql` (should run the Unix Executable file `psql`) gives me the same error.

---

Resources that didn't help me any further:

- [Createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL: role "tom" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973018/createuser-could-not-connect-to-database-postgres-fatal-role-tom-does-not-e)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/how-to-run-psql-on-mac-os-x
- [Psql could not connect to server: No such file or directory, 5432 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin"` you are telling the system that all the commands you need are in that single directory. Since you also need standard system utilities like `wc` you also need to include the directories where they reside in your `PATH`. Normally you would do this to simply add the postgres directories to the list of directories searched for commands:

```
export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin:$PATH"
```