# How can I make new user in postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, virtualenv

How can I make postgres work with django in a virtualenv?

Errors :

1. New Roles are being created but I can't see them in pg_hba.conf
2. CMD: `createdb -U postgres -T template_postgis fixmystreet`
   gives an error both inside virtualenv and on root:

   `Error : createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for  user "postgres"`

FYI: I am new to both django and postgres so I'm doing https://github.com/visiblegovernment/django-fixmystreet/wiki/Installation to get familiar with them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: solved : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471571/how-to-configure-postgresql-for-the-first-time

Comment: Please always post the code that you're having problems with. Just describing what it's supposed to do and what the results are doesn't enable people to identify what's causing the problem.